# Flutter MaterialPageRoute WidgetBuilder runs twice

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm creating a page that has a TextField, when user enters 3+ char in it I fetch rows, from a database, that contain the inserted text. In the example I provide I simulate this by getting a List. After this a list is presented to the user, the user can tap one of the rows to go to another page.

[gist example](https://gist.github.com/NCSantos/3ba65ba244db7c3c90080afea461ef68)

My problem is that when I tap a row MaterialPageRoute WidgetBuilder runs twice, this is the log:

```
---------- onTap ----------
---------- MaterialPageRoute ----------
---------- SecondPage build ----------
---------- MaterialPageRoute ----------
---------- SecondPage build ----------
```

Can someone explain this behavior and also how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: This is the desired behavior. Build can be called anytimes.  You may want to see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52249578/how-to-deal-with-unwanted-widget-build

Comment: A few days ago I also asked that and that was the answer. But this is also for the  MaterialPageRoute WidgetBuilder?

Comment: Seems like so. Anyway you should not care about how many times "build" is called. In no circunstances this should have any impact on your application

Comment: This odd behaviors are strange to me. If I create the list in a `initState` the  MaterialPageRoute WidgetBuilder is run only once.

Comment: @NCSantos that's correct, but then it will never update when your app re-renders. Like Remi said, you shouldn't be concerned with too many builds, the Flutter widget tree is optimized for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem. This is because you didn't add any condition to `FutureBuilder`. So when you are using `setState()` it gets called for the next time.

You can solve it using a flag in `Future` function so that it is invoked for the first time only. Eg:

```
bool flag = true;
flag?FutureBuilder(
future: getData(),
builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snap){
  if(snap.connectionState != ConnectionState.done){
     return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
  }else{
     return populate();
  }
},
):Container();
 Future getData()async{
    flag = false;
    return await fetchFromDatabase();
 }
```