# How to prevent screen rebuild after user gets back from opened url

Tags: ios, flutter

I'm currently using launch_url package in my flutter project.

```
  url_launcher: ^5.0.1
```

I have complex screen and I'm using `launch(url)` to open youtube links.

```
             child: Center(
               child: IconButton(
                   icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow, color: Colors.white),
                   onPressed: ()  {
                      launch(section['url']);
                   },
                   iconSize: 96.0),
             ),
```

I having issue with this feature on iOS(Android version works fine). When user opens youtube url and tap "Done" button. App rebuilds last screen - so user lost current scroll position on screen and he need to wait a second to be able to scroll.
[youtube screen opened by launch(url)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vYkk.jpg)

Android work fine, and there is no screen rebuild after user gets back from screen that was opened by `launch(url)`

How can I prevent screen rebuild on iOS after getting back from `launch(url)` opened screen? I'm able to restore scroll position or rebuild, but I'm user still needs to wait a part of second till screen rebuild ends and he can't scroll immediately

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't stop Flutter from rebuilding. You should probably take a look at the reason why the rebuild takes so long. Is there a way you can speed up the rebuild by maintaining state?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with unwanted widget build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52249578/how-to-deal-with-unwanted-widget-build)

Comment: I've tried suggesting from that post. Even if I save full widget three in a variable it still takes some time to rebuild so user can't scroll imediatelly