# Flutter rebuild previous widget in the background?

Tags: performance, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

When performing any action on a page like moving to a new page from the existing a rebuild is happening to the previous one .

FYI https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11655

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: See this comment https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11655#issuecomment-348287396 from the Flutter technical lead.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I do studied that yet I couldn't get enough knowledge about it.

Comment: You may want to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52249578/how-to-deal-with-unwanted-widget-build