# How to get realtime updates from firestore and yet keep build method pure?

Tags: flutter, stream, google-cloud-firestore

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52249579/7633722):

> The build method is designed in such a way that it should be pure/without side effects.

and

> This means that the build method should not trigger an http call or modify any state.

But this contradicts with [firestore plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cloud_firestore) usage example(condensed for briefness):

```
class BookList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('books').snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
      //  do something with books
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Anytime when `build` method called, `builder` function from `StreamBuilder` called as well.

What I tried:

```
...
stream: Firestore.instance.collection('books').snapshots().distinct(),
...
```

Neither advice from previously mentioned answer works for this case.

Comment: The fact that `builder` is called again has nothing to do with the purity of the function though ¬ and it is totally normal

Comment: @Rémi Rousselet, but then it will fetch data again, this time needlessly, which is bad, isn't it?

Comment: No it won't. The builder is called again, but the data isn't fetched again

Comment: @Rémi Rousselet, it's cool, so if `builder` can be called repeatedly without problems, it is differs to use `StatefulWidget` approach instead of  plain `StatelessWidget`?

Comment: Yes because with the `StatelessWidget`, opening the keyboard for example, will make your build method create a new stream. Which may cause extraneous firebase request (although it's hard to verify).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is the same actually: Make a `StatefulWidget`

```
class Foo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FooState createState() => _FooState();
}

class _FooState extends State<Foo> {
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> stream;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    stream = Firestore.instance.collection('books').snapshots();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: stream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        //  do something with books
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but I added prints in `build` and `builder` and sadly they both printed anytime after, for example, I changed phone orientation

Comment: @D31 But as said in the post from the answer you linked (which is mine btw :D): It doesn't matter. `build` (and therefore `builder`) can be called any time.

Comment: In fact, precisely because the `builder` is triggered so regularly is why it should be side-effect free. The actual work of getting the data happens in your `stream` property, which doesn't get triggered for every `build`.