# Why Root Widget gets build twice?

Tags: flutter

I have this very basic test app:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("ROOT WIDGET ");
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue),),
    );
  }
}
```

Log output debug:

> Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone X in debug mode...
>
> Found saved certificate choice "XXX". To clear, use "flutter config".
>   Signing iOS app for device deployment using developer identity: "XXX"
>
> Running Xcode build...
>
> Xcode build done.                                           39,4s
>
> Installing and launching...
>
> flutter: ROOT WIDGET
>
> Syncing files to device iPhone X...
>
> flutter: ROOT WIDGET

Log output with `flutter run --release`

> Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone X in release mode...
>
> Found saved certificate choice "XXX". To clear, use "flutter config".
>
> Signing iOS app for device deployment using developer identity: "XXX"
>
> Running pod install...
>   1,2s
>
> Running Xcode build...
>                                                                                             ├─Building Dart code...                                    15,8s
>
> ├─Generating dSYM file...                                   0,1s
>
> ├─Stripping debug symbols...                                0,0s
>
> ├─Assembling Flutter resources...                           0,7s
>
> └─Compiling, linking and signing...                        48,3s
>
> Xcode build done.                                           67,4s
>
> Installing and launching...
>   6,8s
>
> To quit, press "q".
>
> flutter: ROOT WIDGET

As you can see it only happens in debug mode.

The reason why I ask is, in my real app, I use a `WebView`. The function `onWebViewCreated(WebViewController controller)` of the `WebView` is only called the first time, so that the `WebViewController` is always null in debug mode.

Comment: It doesn't matter and you shouldn't bother about this. If it cause issues for you, then you're likely doing something you shouldn't inside your _build_ method. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52249578/how-to-deal-with-unwanted-widget-build

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but as you can see I´m doing bascially nothing in my build method.

Comment: Oh I think I see what you mean, in the other app I initialize a webView in the build method, that´s probably something I shouldn´t do. But then, I have to initialize my webView somewhere, where if not in the build method.

Comment: That's likely it :) You'll want to do that inside an _initState_ or similar

Comment: It works now. You saved me from going crazy! In fact, your linked answer is so good that I just sent it as a note to my entire team. Thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify the solution - to turn MyApp into a stateful widget and call init methods from initState?
I have the same issue with redux and the solution is a bit unclear from this conversation.

Comment: @Alexander Semenov Yes in this particilular case with the webview we only initialized it in the initState method and the problem didnt occur anymore.

Comment: Nice catch, might be worth to post this as answer

Answer (score 7):

I have been getting this issue on

> Flutter 1.22.0 • channel stable

**Deleting the app from my emulator/physical phone and reinstalling fixes the issue. Delete the app from the emulator/physical from System Settings/Apps and reinstall in debug mode.**

I have no idea why but time to time my main widget keeps on getting rebuild exactly twice and I dont do anything in my main widget no SetStates or no futurebuilder. I think this is a flutter internal bug.

Answer (score 1):

The clue might be here

```
Installing and launching... //We are launching the app , the code bundled with it it's executed briefly before it "sync" to allow hot reload

flutter: ROOT WIDGET //The bundled code executes

Syncing files to device iPhone X... //We start the sync, hot reload triggers an app rebuild 

flutter: ROOT WIDGET //The live code executes
```

If you comment the print, then hot-reload, then uncomment the print, you should only see one "ROOT WIDGET".

Answer (score -3):

I have same issue, and I found that it's not flutter's problem, it's `vscode`.
try running in `android studio`.

Comment: How can it help fix the issue with the environment in the question?

Comment: I don't know exactly, maybe my answer is not related this issue. but when I was using vscode, app builded twice every time. it does not happen on android studio