# Flutter Expanded throwing error when waiting for data from Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I've got a problem with data which I'm returning from Firestore. I need to get some emails using the [Cloud Firestore Plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cloud_firestore#-readme-tab-):

```
class _EmailPageState extends State<EmailPage> {
  //StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot> _emails;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //_emails = _getEmails();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Refer user'),
      ),
      body: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Form(... form code)
      Expanded(child: _getEmails()),
      ],
    )
}
```

Since _emails is not populated until the data returns from Firestore, I get:

```
flutter: The following assertion was thrown building Expanded(flex: 1, dirty):
flutter: A build function returned null.
flutter: The offending widget is: Expanded(flex: 1)
flutter: Build functions must never return null. To return an empty space that causes the building widget to
flutter: fill available room, return "new Container()". To return an empty space that takes as little room as
flutter: possible, return "new Container(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)".
```

I don't understand how to fix the error. The view is displaying correct. But I don't want to have the error.

```
 StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot> _getEmails() {
    final query = Firestore.instance
        .collection('emails')
        .where("referer", isEqualTo: uid)
        .snapshots();

    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: query,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return Text('Loading...');
          default:
            return _makeList(snapshot);
        }
      },
    );

    //setState(() {
      //_emails = emailList;
    //});

    //return emailList;
  }

  ListView _makeList(AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    return ListView(
      children: snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(document['email']),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `_getEmails()` is returning null before data arrives. It should return something like `CircularProgressIndicator()` instead. If you show that function you can get more help, but you can use sample code from here, too: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html

Edit: ok I see your edit. I guess it does not return null after all. However, `Expanded` needs to be a child of a `Row` or a `Column`. You should either wrap it with one of these, or use `Container`, `Center`, etc. to do your positioning.

Also, there is no need to cache the `StreamBuilder`, you should not cache widgets. You can cache the stream, however. You should at least change your code to be something like

```
class _EmailPageState extends State<EmailPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Refer user'),
      ),
      body: Center(child: _getEmails())
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok ... maybe I should add more code. There is something I left out. If I don't use `Expanded` the widget doesn't render. Please see my edit.

Comment: Thank you for the tip about caching ... I removed it.

Comment: I don't see where the build function is returning null... You could try this: in your `_makeList` function, see if `snapshot.data.documents.isEmpty` is ever true. Maybe ListView having an empty list is it, who knows.

Comment: I will. Thank you. You mentioned that I can cache the stream and not the `StreamBuilder`. How would I do that. Can you give me an example?

Comment: Sure, here is an example of it for `FutureBuilder`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52249579/679553 He creates the `Future` in `initState` and puts it into a field in the class. Later he uses it in a `FutureBuilder`. This way you are sure that the same `Future` instance will be available to `FutureBuilder` and this will prevent some unwanted rebuilds. You can do the same for `Stream` and `StreamBuilder`.