# FutureBuilder running two times bug

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I added debug point for

- `future: _futureData`
- `Future getRegister1() async{` first run `getRegister1()` and then `future: _futureData` and again two times run `getRegister1()` after
  that screen comes _mainCategory State Widget

  ```
  class _mainCategory extends State<mainCategory3> {
    Future _futureData;

    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();    
        _futureData = getRegister1();
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      return Scaffold(
  ```

  FutureBuilder inside Body

  ```
  body: FutureBuilder(
    future: _futureData,
       builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
  ```

  getRegister1()

  ```
     Future getRegister1() async {
      //this data coming from cache (sqflite)
      List _catLocal = (await HelperDatabase1().displayRegisterCat());
      List _defCatLocal = (await HelperDatabase1().display());
  ...
  }
  ```

full code https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31838

[image]

Comment: what is `getRegister()` used for (not `getRegister1`)? or is it just a typo? also add some `print()`s to your app and post the log output, as i am completely lost in your current control flow description

Comment: why don't you remove the code inside initState and just use getRegister1() instead of _futureData ?

Comment: @diegoveloper actually what he does is better https://stackoverflow.com/a/52249579/679553

Comment: Yeah I know but looks like it isn't working. I would use setState or streambuilder instead of FutureBuilder

Comment: @pskink two times run on my FutureBuilder

Comment: @diegoveloper do you have any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: @GazihanAlankus do you have any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: would you post the logs? are you saying that `getRegister1()` method is called twice? or `State#build()` method is called twice? add some `print()`s in those two methods and post your logs

Comment: `build()` method calling again and again

Comment: where do you use `subCategory` widget? also try to name you classes [UpperCamelCase](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/effective-dart/style#do-name-types-using-uppercamelcase) way

Comment: the subCategory is next page. It's a new Stateful Widget same like this class

Comment: `_mainCategory` is a `State` for `subCategory`? right? your class naming is just horrible

Comment: no. this is full code. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31838

Comment: ok @pskink I change my class name, before that, I need to fix this issue

Comment: so what is `_mainCategory` actually? `class _mainCategory extends State<subCategory>` or `class _mainCategory extends State<mainCategory3>` - i am lost...

Comment: @pskink any solution?

Comment: i have no idea where you use your `mainCategory3` and where you are rebuilding it

Comment: `mainCategory3` is my StatefullWidget. `subCategory` is next page StatefullWidget.

Comment: next page? what next page? why dont you simply post the complete code? whee is `mainCategory3` used?

Comment: @diegoveloper if you remove futureData in `initState` it will loose scroll position when you come back(one examoke) right?.