# Flutter status bar change color dynamically

Tags: flutter, dart

Most of the answers about this topics suggests the follow solution.

```
import 'package:flutter_statusbarcolor/flutter_statusbarcolor.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    FlutterStatusbarcolor.setStatusBarColor(Colors.white);
```

But according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52249578/how-to-deal-with-unwanted-widget-build)

> The build method is designed in such a way that it should be pure/without side effects.

The proposed solution has one drawback - it's does not work in case when I have to change status color depends on current screen.

Is there way how I can handle it?

Comment: What do you want, exactly? Change the status bar color according to the current route?

Comment: Yes, exacly what I want

Comment: Why don't you call `setStatusBarColor` in the `initState` of each `Widget` that you want a different color? Indeed, calling it at `build` makes no sense.

Comment: It will not work in some cases when I make push / pop

Comment: Makes sense. Hold on, I got something for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `AnnotatedRegion` to specify a different `statusBarColor` for each route:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  Map<String, WidgetBuilder> get routes {
    return {
      '/': (context) {
        return AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
          value: const SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.blue),
          child: Scaffold(body: Home()),
        );
      },
      '/foo': (context) {
        return AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
          value: const SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.red),
          child: Scaffold(body: Foo()),
        );
      },
    };
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      routes: routes,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Very useful to dynamically change the theme, thanks a lot!

Comment: it successfully changes navigation bar colour but for some reason colour of status bar remains same as set by first screen.