# TextField reloads FutureBuilder when pressed/left in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

The user can either enter the answer with InputChips or manually type it in the TextField. When I try with InputChips, the correct answer is not detected. When I try to manually type it, the FutureBuilder reloads when I enter and leave the TextField. What is the reason?
The Future function should only be called once because it fetches a random document from Firestore, splits the String and scrambles the different pieces. It is some form of quiz.

```dart
class _buildPhrases extends State<PhrasesSession>{
  TextEditingController _c;
  String _text = "initial";

  @override
  void initState(){
    _c = new TextEditingController();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose(){
    _c?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final Arguments args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    var height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;



    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(flex: 2, child: _buildRest(context),),
          Flexible(flex: 5,
            child: FutureBuilder(
              future: getEverything(args.colName),
              builder: (context, snapshot){
                if(!snapshot.hasData){
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
                }else{

                  return Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Flexible(flex: 1, child: Text(snapshot.data[1]),),
                      Divider(),
                      Flexible(flex: 2, child: Container(
                        child: TextField(
                        onChanged: (t){
                            _text += "$t ";
                            if(_c.text == snapshot.data[0]){
                              return print("CORRECT ANSWER");
                            }
                        },
                        controller: _c,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          enabled: true,

                      ),
                      ),),
                      Flexible(flex: 3,
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.length - 2,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index){
                            if(index>snapshot.data.length - 2){
                              return null;
                            }else{
                              return Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                                child: InputChip(
                                  label: Text(snapshot.data[index + 2]),
                                  onPressed: (){
                                    _c.text += "${snapshot.data[index  + 2]} ";
                                  },
                                ),
                              );
                            }
                          },
                        ))
                    ],
                  );
                }
              },
            ),)
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You have to initialize your Future in initState. Take a lot on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52249578/how-to-deal-with-unwanted-widget-build

Comment: @RubensMelo My Future needs the String that is passed from another route, though. See the `Arguments args = ...`. Any idea how I get it in the initState?

Comment: You can access that with `widget.args.colName`

Comment: @RubensMelo I'm not sure how to initialise my Future. In the example you sent it is `future = Future.value(42);`. In my case I would have to move my Future into the class and initialise like: `getEverything(widget.args.colName) = Future.value(???)` what would be the correct way? thanks

Answer (score 7):

Let's solve this in parts.

**When I try to manually type it the FutureBuilder reloads when I enter and leave the TextField. What is the reason?**

This is hapenning because when the keyboard is showing or hidding the flutter framework calls `build` method of your widget and this default behavior is the reason why your `FutureBuilder` is realoading. You should avoid call network methods inside `build` method and I advise you to use BLoC pattern to handle state of your widget.

**My Future needs the String that is passed from another route, though. See the Arguments args = .... Any idea how I get it in the initState?**

Well if you need `context` instance to get this `String` you can't access current context inside `initState` method because your widget isn't full initialized yet. A simple way to solve this in your case but not the best is verify if the data was already fetched from network or not.

```
Future _myNetworkFuture; // declare this as member of your stateWidgetClass

Widget build(BuildContext context){
   final Arguments args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
   var height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
   var width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

   // this line says if(_myNetworkFuture == null) do the thing.
   _myNetworkFuture ??= getEverything(args.colName);

   return ...
   Flexible(flex: 5,
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: _myNetworkFuture,
          builder: (context, snapshot){ 
           // ...
          }
}
```

With this approach when flutter framework calls `build` method if you already fetched the data you don't download the data again. But I really advise you to use BLoC pattern in this kind of situation.

Comment: Is it okay to just use the bloc pattern in one part of the app or do I have to implement it every where?

Comment: Wow, thank you for this great answer! Helped me and I found it very quickly.