# const/static/final `CustomPainter` and `CustomClipper` implementation

Tags: flutter, dart

In SO question [How to deal with unwanted widget build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52249578/how-to-deal-with-unwanted-widget-build)
 asked and answered by Remi Rousselet(author of Provider package), it says using const in front of the class constructor helps avoid unwanted widget builds.

I am having performance issues with my `CustomPainter` and `CustomClipper` and want to apply this tactic. My `CustomClipper` clips a child widget with a certain custom shape and my `CustomPainter` paints a shadow according to the clipped shapes boundaries. **These two shapes don't change at all**. Only mutable object is inside of the child `Text` leaf widget. `Text` string and length has no effect on the shape of custom clipper and painter.

`shouldRepaint` and `shouldReclip` are returning false by the way.

Question is how can i make these two classes const or static so that they don't get rebuild with every build by their parent widgets while allowing the `Text` widget change its content with the builds? Can you think of anything else to omit unnecessary builds for a widget which does not change at all?

To give more insight as to what I am building: I have several Flutter_Map markers as widgets on the world map. And these markers have a custom clipped shape and a custom shadow to go along with the boundary shape. And inside of this custom shape I have a `Marquee` `Text` Widget which gets its values from `FireStore`.

This Marquee has an animation (like a text ticker moving left and right in order to fit a whole sentence in few pixels width).

The markers Sizes definitely do not change. But I pan the map and their coordinates change in the screen.

single_marker_widget.dart

```
class SingleMarkerWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Table table;  //filleduchaos this is where I pass the Text widgets string
  const SingleMarkerWidget({Key key, this.table}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _SingleMarkerWidgetState createState() => _SingleMarkerWidgetState();
}

class _SingleMarkerWidgetState extends State<SingleMarkerWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipShadowPath(
      clipper: _SingleMarkerClipper(),
      shadow: Shadow(
        color: Colors.grey[800],
        blurRadius: 25,
        offset: Offset(5.0, 8.0),
      ),
      child: RepaintBoundary(
        child: Marquee(
          textList: [
            widget.table.tableGame.gameName,
            widget.table.tableVenue.venueName,
            widget.table.tableVenue.venueDistrict,
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _SingleMarkerClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  getClip(Size size) {
    print(
        '_SingleMarkerClipper ==== getClip'); //1- THIS PRINT PRINTS WAY TOO OFTEN. THIS IS WHAT I AM TRYING TO GET RID OF.
    //....
    //DRAW THE CUSTOM SHAPE
    //....
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper oldClipper) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

clip_shadow_path.dart

```
@immutable
class ClipShadowPath extends StatelessWidget {
  final Shadow shadow;
  final CustomClipper<Path> clipper;
  final Widget child;

  const ClipShadowPath({
    @required this.shadow,
    @required this.clipper,
    @required this.child,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('ClipShadowPath ==== build');
    return CustomPaint(
      painter: _ClipShadowShadowPainter(
        clipper: this.clipper,
        shadow: this.shadow,
      ),
      child: ClipPath(child: this.child, clipper: this.clipper),
    );
  }
}

class _ClipShadowShadowPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Shadow shadow;
  final CustomClipper<Path> clipper;

  const _ClipShadowShadowPainter(
      {@required this.shadow, @required this.clipper});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    print(
        '_ClipShadowShadowPainter ==== paint'); //2- THIS PRINT PRINTS WAY TOO OFTEN. THIS IS WHAT I AM TRYING TO GET RID OF.
    var paint = shadow.toPaint();
    var clipPath = clipper.getClip(size).shift(shadow.offset);
    canvas.drawPath(clipPath, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a code snippet to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I posted the code.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your `ClipShadowPath` in a RepaintBoundary too?

Comment: @RémiRousselet yes I tried wrapping `ClipShadowPath` widget in a `RepaintBoundary` in single_marker_widget.dart if you are talking about that. I haven't tried wrapping `CustomPaint` widget in a `RepaintBoundary` in clip_shadow_path.dart though.