# Build function in StatelessWidget keeps refiring

Tags: flutter, dart

Consider the following `StatelessWidget`:

```
class SwitchScreen extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final testService = Provider.of<TestService>(context);  // Line 1
        Future( () { 
            Navigator.of(context).push(   // Segment 2
                 MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => TestScreen())  // Segment 2
            );    // Segment 2
        });

        return Scaffold(body: Center( child: Text("lol") ) );
    }
}
```

The widget is directly below the root in the widget tree and wrapped by a `ChangeNotifierProvider`:

```
void main() => runApp(new Main());

class Main extends StatefulWidget {
    _MainState createState() => _MainState();
}

class _MainState extends State<Main> {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
            title: 'SampleProgram',
            home: ChangeNotifierProvider<TestService>(
                builder: (_) { return TestService(); } ,
                child: SwitchScreen(),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

The service associated with the provider, `TestService`, is currently empty. `TestScreen` is simply another `StatelessWidget` which includes `AppBar` wrapped inside a `Scaffold`.

I would expect the program to finish rendering the `SwitchScreen`, navigate to `TestScreen` to fulfill the future, and finally render the `AppBar` inside `TestScreen`. However, every time it enters the `TestScreen` view, something appears to trigger a rebuild of `SwitchScreen`. The app then bounces back to `SwitchScreen`, moves to `TestScreen` to fulfill the future, and repeats this process. By using debug Print statements I'm sure that the `build` method of `SwitchScreen` is called immediately after `TestScreen` finishes rendering.

The interesting thing is that if I comment out Line 1, the `build` method won't be re-triggered. Similarly if I replace the entirety of Segment 2 with anything else, say a print statement, the `build` method won't keep firing either. I suspected that `Navigator` is resulting in some value change in `TestService`, forcing `SwitchScreen` to rebuild, so I overrode the `notifyListeners` method in `TestService` since this method is the only way `SwitchScreen` can be affected by `TestService`.

```
class TestService with ChangeNotifier {
    @override
    void notifyListeners() {
        print("Triggering SwitchScreen's build method");
    }
}
```

But no string is printed out. Right now I'm very curious about what's causing the rebuilding and what roles do the Provider and the Navigator play in this. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You can't have such thing in your build method. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52249578/how-to-deal-with-unwanted-widget-build

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling

```
final testService = Provider.of<TestService>(context);
```

Use

```
final testService = Provider.of<TestService>(context, listen: false);
```

Using the above line in a build method won’t cause this widget to rebuild when notifyListeners is called.