# When using Navigator MaterialPageRoute previous page builder function also runs

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have 4 routing page 
page 1, page 2, page 3 , page 4,

when i use Navigator from page 1 to page 2,
page 1 MaterialPageRoute builder function runs that's ok and
when i navigate from page 2 to page 3 
first page 2 MaterialPageRoute builder functions runs then page 1 MaterialPageRoute builder runs again ,
when i navigate to page 4 from page 3 
first  MateriaPageRoute builder function for page 3 runs then page 2 and then page 1.

Comment: Are you using `Navigator.push(...)` or something else?

Comment: Likely because of how you've made your buildfunction, have a read of this see if it solves the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52249578/how-to-deal-with-unwanted-widget-build