# flutter refresh rebuild childwidget twice

Tags: flutter

i have this code

```dart
 RefreshIndicator(
            key: _refreshIndicatorKey,
            onRefresh: onrefreh,//don't do anything
            child: TodoPage())
```

and TodoPage likes that

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('tt');
    final todoBloc = TodoProvider.of(context);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Title")),
      body: Center(
        child: Column()
   ......
}
```

sometimes when i even touch the main page  i can see 'tt' String twice on bebugconsole i think refreshindicator make todoPage rebuild
and when i refresh definitely i can see two 'tt' result on debug console why they rebuild twice? and if i want only one time when i surely swipe the page to refresh

Comment: Why does it matter? This shouldn't have any impact on your app

Comment: i just wander and i think if app size is getting bigger i think it's not good because it rebuild twice

Comment: and also in my case when  widget be rebuilt there is streambuilder and that requests api(http.get(uri)) so everytime i refresh api is rqeusted twice

Comment: That's unrelated and your fault. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52249578/how-to-deal-with-unwanted-widget-build

Comment: thanks i think this is also related to my problem but i also want to know why refreshindicator do that. i thnk scrollNotification.depth==0 this line make children's build methods rebuild. what if i change that condition and how can i?