# ChangeNotifier dispose model too early

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-provider

I am use Firestore transaction for avoid race condition of add more than 1 user to chat. If transaction timeout, I show error dialog.

But when I move this logic to `Model2` with `ChangeNotifier` (and `Provider`) it now show error:

> Unhandled Exception: A Model2 was used after being disposed. Once you
>   have called dispose() on a Model2, it can no longer be used.

(No issue with Firestore transaction. This is expected):

> PlatformException(9, Transaction failed all retries.: Every document
>   read in a transaction must also be written in that transaction., null)

It seem `ChangeNotifier` is call `dispose()` too early?

This mean it not allow me to handle error of race condition because it is already dispose.

**Model:**

```
class Model2 extends ChangeNotifier {

...

bool userAdded;

      Future<bool> addUser() async {

    try {
      await Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
        DocumentSnapshot chatRoomDocSnapshot =
            await transaction.get(chatRoomDocRef);
        bool userInChat = await chatRoomDocSnapshot[‘userInChat'];

        if (userInChat == false) {
            await transaction.update(chatRoomDocSnapshot.reference, {
              ‘userInChat': true,
            });
        }
      });

    await chatUserRef.setData({
      ‘User’: user,
    });

      userAdded = true;
notifyListeners();



    } catch (e) {
print(e);
      userAdded = false;
notifyListeners();

    }
    return userAdded;
      }
```

**Provider** (in stateful widget):

```
fetchData();

return ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Model1, Model2>(
initialBuilder: (_) => Model2(),
  builder: (_, model1, model2) => model2
    ..string = model1.string,
),
  child: Consumer<Model2>(
    builder: (context, model2, _) =>

...
await model2.addUser();
...
```

Anyone know solution?

Thanks!

Update:

Issue is not throw if I remove `fetchData();` from `build` method before `ChangeNotifierProxyProvider` .

But why is this fix the issue?

Comment: This snippet is not enough to reproduce the issue. It could be multiple things, like related to navigation or listeners not properly disposed.

Comment: @RémiRousselet Not issue with navigation because it still throw if I remove navigator. I am not call `dispose()` anywhere. `provider` handle `dispose()` automatic right?

Comment: @RémiRousselet I have fix issue by remove function from `build` method. Why this fix issue?

Comment: Ah, you're calling `fetchData` in the build method?

Comment: That's pretty bad. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52249578/how-to-deal-with-unwanted-widget-build

Comment: @RémiRousselet Thanks! But why this throw error with Model? I was expect different error for this

Comment: I agree that the snippet you've provided is not enough for the community to clearly see whats wrong. Since you've mentioned that when `fetchData()` was removed from the build method, it could have something in it that was causing the error. Could you provide the [a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Going through the comments, it's likely that calling `fetchData()` rebuilds the entire screen - calling the `dispose()` method. If you're still having issues, I suggest providing logs and the code inside `fetchData()` for better context.