# Flutter provider notify only selected listeners

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I'm fighting with Flutter's provider and can't understand all of it's possibilities.
The thing is that for example I have such widgets structure:

```
Widget_A
--Widget_B
----Widget_C
----Widget_D
--Widget_E
--Widget_F
```

Simple example is *TODO* list. Imagine you have `categories`, `add_field` and `todos_list`. Each is a separate widget. Than you change `categories` so `todos_list` should be reloaded to show todos from selected category. Later you add todo using `add_field` so `todos_list` also need to be updated because of new record. How can I achieve something like this?

PS: I was trying to separate all the stuff to the different Provider classes, but effect is the same: if widget uses Provider.of(context) it will be updated no matter what. And as I should combine data from 2 providers there will be widget that is connected to the both providers so the result will be endless loop. Still.

Comment: The fact that you have an endless loop of update, added to the fact that you're asking this question, shows that you're doing something anti pattern.

Comment: Which anti pattern? Data flow isn't so easy. One of the widgets should be updated if 2 other widgets updates... May be there's some widget structure problem, but I don't see it.

Comment: Your dataflow is the problem. It should be a unidirectional dataflow.

Comment: What do you mean? It's kind of unidirectional. But as I understand Provider doesn't care about direction. If widget uses selected Provider it will be updated... Right? At least a see something like this

Comment: This is probably not the only problem that you have, nor is the example used strictly identical to yours, but you may want to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52249578/how-to-deal-with-unwanted-widget-build.

Comment: Thank, you. I'll try to separate provider into few different providers and modify logic. But still... Example is todo list. Imagine you have ```categories```, ```add_field``` and ```todos_list```. Each is a separate widget. Than you change ```categories``` so ```todos_list``` should be reloaded, later you add todo using ```add_field``` so ```todos_list``` also need to be updated. How can I achieve something like this?

Comment: It depends on your model and use-case, but you should be able to use `Selector`.

Comment: please, extend your answer. What do you mean by depends on model and use-case