# Draggable element with tracking x and y position in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am capturing an image and want to do some calculation on that image, for that I need to get the position of some spots on the image. For that, I am using the draggable element, my idea is to drag an element to spot on the image, get x and y position of the draggable elements to do calculations.

I have used the following code

```
body: Container(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.file(File(widget.imagePath)),
            Draggable(
              axis: Axis.vertical,

              child: Text('_________', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 90) ),
              feedback:Text('____',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 90)) ,
              childWhenDragging: Text(''),

            ),

            SizedBox(height: 50.0,),

          ],
        ),
      )
```

Problem with this is
 1. when an element is getting drag, that element position should move with touch, currently wile drag, element getting shifted by a few pixels.
2. Element position is not getting shifted to final drag position, when i remove touch element go back to original position.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 23):

To use a [Draggable](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Draggable-class.html) like this,

1. You'll need to be able to set the element's position, something like `Positioned` and its `left`,`top`.
2. Then you'll need to get the ending coordinates of the drag, using `dragDetails` from `onDragEnd: (dragDetails) { }`

Here's a simple sample to start you off:

```
Positioned(
  left: _x,
  top: _y,
  child: Draggable(
    child: FlutterLogo(size: _logoSize),
    feedback: FlutterLogo(size: _logoSize),
    childWhenDragging: Container(),
    onDragEnd: (dragDetails) {
      setState(() {
        _x = dragDetails.offset.dx;
        // if applicable, don't forget offsets like app/status bar
        _y = dragDetails.offset.dy - appBarHeight - statusBarHeight;
      });
    },
  ),
)
```

[image]

Also a good intro to Draggable [medium/A Deep Dive Into Draggable and DragTarget in Flutter](https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-deep-dive-into-draggable-and-dragtarget-in-flutter-487919f6f1e4)

*(if you don't want to use Draggable, you can also use a `GestureDetector` to accomplish the same thing, but a little more work)*

Comment: setState() every dragged pixel, how to avoid children re-render?

Comment: Yes I have the same problem, I think when you wrap it in a widget you can rebuild that specific widget: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52249578/how-to-deal-with-unwanted-widget-build

Comment: you can also use stateful builder: https://medium.com/flutterdevs/can-stateful-builder-step-into-shoes-of-stateful-widget-81af58824ed0

Answer (score 2):

TWL's solution works, but do note that [`Positioned`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html) must be a descendent of a `Stack` widget.