# How to implement FutureBuilder with already obtained future

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm a little confused about how to implement Flutter's FutureBuilder according to the docs. I have a Future Builder here which work, with the only problem being that it every time the build method is run so to is the future being used:

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: DBProvider.db.getUser(),
    builder: (_, userData) {
        switch (userData.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.none:
                return Container();
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
                return Container();
            case ConnectionState.active:
            case ConnectionState.done:
                newUser = userData.data;
                return ListView(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    children: <Widget>[
                        ... // Lot's of things
                    ],
                );
        }
        return null;
    },
),
```

I then realize the importance of this part of the docs where it says the future must be "obtained earlier" so this problem doesn't happen:

> The future must have been obtained earlier, e.g. during
>   State.initState, State.didUpdateConfig, or
>   State.didChangeDependencies. It must not be created during the
>   State.build or StatelessWidget.build method call when constructing the
>   FutureBuilder. If the future is created at the same time as the
>   FutureBuilder, then every time the FutureBuilder's parent is rebuilt,
>   the asynchronous task will be restarted.

Here's where my question comes from, I understand what those words are saying, but in terms of writing the code according to that what exactly does mean / look like?

Do I simply make a function and call it in initState like this:

```
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getUser();
}

_getUser() async {
    newUser = await DBProvider.db.getUser();
}
```

In this case what goes in the future argument of the FutureBuilder? Or this completely not right?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52249578/how-to-deal-with-unwanted-widget-build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are on the right track. The easiest way to deal with this is to store a Future variable in your state. In `initState` make the API call and store the Future. You can then pass this Future to FutureBuilder.

Something like this:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  State createState() {
    return MyState();
  }
}

class MyState extends State<MyWidget> {
  Future userFuture;
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Note here we are not awaiting the user, but rather storing
    // the future in the variable
    userFuture = DBProvider.db.getUser();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: userFuture,
      builder: (BuildContext, snapshot) {
        ...
      }
    );
  }
}
```