# Why does my StatefulWidget lose its state?

Tags: flutter

I'm building a tinder-like card swipe mechanism where I have a list of cards widget in a `Stack` widget. The first card is wrapped inside a `Dismissible` widget which, on dismiss, dismiss the top card and add a new one at the bottom.

My issue here is that, when the first card is dismissed and the second one becomes the first, that card is momentarily disposed and `initState` is called again

But, as Linus Torvalds once said,

> "Talk is cheap, show me the code"

so I put together a example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Container(color: Colors.white, child: CardStack()),
    );
  }
}

class CardStack extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CardStackState createState() => _CardStackState();
}

class _CardStackState extends State<CardStack> {
  final List<String> _postIds = ["1", "2", "3"];
  int _nextId = 4;

  _updatePosts(DismissDirection dir) {
    setState(() {
      _postIds.removeAt(0);
      _postIds.add((_nextId++).toString());
    });
  }

  List<Widget> _buildCards() {
    List<Widget> cards = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < _postIds.length; ++i) {
      if (i == 0) {
        cards.insert(
            0,
            Dismissible(
              key: UniqueKey(),
              onDismissed: _updatePosts,
              child: Card(key: ValueKey(_postIds[i]), postId: _postIds[i]),
            ));
      } else {
        cards.insert(0, Card(key: ValueKey(_postIds[i]), postId: _postIds[i]));
      }
    }
    return cards;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: _buildCards(),
    );
  }
}

class Card extends StatefulWidget {
  Card({Key key, this.postId}) : super(key: key);

  final String postId;

  @override
  _CardState createState() => _CardState();
}

class _CardState extends State<Card> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("Init state card with id ${widget.postId}");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 200,
      width: 200,
      color: Colors.blueAccent,
      child: Center(
        child: Text(widget.postId),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

if I run that it logs

```
I/flutter (26740): Init state card with id 3
I/flutter (26740): Init state card with id 2
I/flutter (26740): Init state card with id 1
// swipe
I/flutter (26740): Init state card with id 4
I/flutter (26740): Init state card with id 2 <- unwanted rebuild
```

I think the rebuild of the first card is due to the fact that is is now wrapped inside the `Dismissible` widget so flutter doesn't know how to reuse the underlying Card widget.

Is there a way to prevent this unwanted rebuild here?

Comment: check out remi rousselet's monolog here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52249578/how-to-deal-with-unwanted-widget-build. So the question for you should be, why do you want to avoid a rebuild? If you want to prevent it, you should reconsider you code design.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is, the location of your `StatefulWidget` is changing inside the widget tree.

It could be that your `StatefulWidget` is conditionally wrapped inside a specific widget, such that your widget tree varies between:

```
SomeWidget
  MyStatefulWidget
```

and:

```
SomeWidget
  AnotherWidget
    MyStatefulWidget
```

By default, Flutter will not understand that `MyStatefulWidget` *moved* inside the widget tree.

Instead, it'll think that the previous `MyStatefulWidget` got removed, and the new one is completely unrelated to the original one.

This leads to `dispose` being called on the previous `State`, and `initState` being called on the new `State`.

---

To prevent this, you have a few solutions.

### Do not conditionally wrap your widget in another one

If you can, this is the best solution:
Refactor your layout such that the widget tree is *always* the same.

For example, if you want to only the first widget in a `ListView` to be dismissible, then instead of:

```dart
ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (_, index) {
    final child = MyStatefulWidget();
    if (index == 0) {
      return Dismissible(key: ValueKey(index), onDismissed: ..., child: child);
    }
  }
)
```

do:

```dart
ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (_, index) {
    return Dismissible(
      key: ValueKey(someValue),
      onDismissed: ...,
      confirmDismiss: (_) async => index == 0, // only first item can be dismissed
      child: MyStatefulWidget();
    );
  }
)
```

This way, the tree does not conditionally change, but the behavior is still conditional

### Use GlobalKey

Less ideal as more costly, but more flexible.

You can use `GlobalKey` to tell Flutter that a specific widget can move from one location to another.

As such, we would be able to write:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  if (something) {
    return SomeTree(
      child: MyStatefulWidget(key: GlobalObjectKey('my widget'));
    );
  } else {
    return AnotherTree(
      child: MyStatefulWidget(key: GlobalObjectKey('my widget'));
    );
  }
}
```

This way, while transitioning from `SomeTree` to `AnotherTree`, the widget `MyStatefulWidget` will preserve its state.

As a little reminder, avoid it if possible. This is relatively costly.

Answer (score 0):

Hi flutter manages its state very wisely.On rebuild if the widget at same state then it won't be rebuild but you have written the `Card()` in the condition so after the dismiss the widget "2" state is changing and its getting rebuilt.
You can build the list once and apply the condition after that.**As Linus Torvalds said ;-)**

```
List<Widget> _buildCards() {
    List<Widget> cards = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < _postIds.length; ++i) {
        cards.insert(0, Card(key: ValueKey(_postIds[i]), postId: _postIds[i]));
    }
    cards[0]=Dismissible(
              key: UniqueKey(),
              onDismissed: _updatePosts,
              child: cards[0]
            ));
    return cards;
  }
```