# Flutter Navigation Re-Render All Page in Histories Stack Page

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

I just realized that flutter re-render all pages in histories stack when navigation changes. In my case I don't want to render page below of all my stack page histories. I just want to render my current page only.

First Page

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context){
  print("1st page");
  return RaisedButton(onPressed: goToSecondPage())
}
```

Second Page

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context){
  print("2nd page");
  return RaisedButton(onPressed: goToThirdPage())
}
```

Third Page

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context){
  print("3rd page");
  return Text("I am Third Page, The Last");
}
```

In my implementation I use `Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SecondPage())` to navigate.

Log
scenario: startup

```
1st page
```

go to second page

```
2nd page
1st page
```

go to third page

```
3rd page
2nd page
1st page
```

back to second page

```
2nd page
1st page
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the current intended behavior with Flutter, see the conversation here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11655

Here is another SO question talking about the same thing: [How to deal with unwanted widget build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52249578/how-to-deal-with-unwanted-widget-build)

And a currently open pull request to change this behavior:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/44731