# How to stop a widget to reload on setState() method in StatefulWidget Class in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, reload, statefulwidget

What I am trying to achieve is to save the state of the Widget i.e it should not refresh when the setState() method is been called.

```
class _GenderSelectionPageState extends State<GenderSelectionPage> {
  bool isFemaleSelected = false;
  AdmobBannerSize bannerSize;
  GlobalKey _globalKey = new GlobalKey();

  bool isLoaded = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    bannerSize = AdmobBannerSize.BANNER;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Container(
          width: width,
          child: new Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Flexible(
                        child: new Hero(
                          tag: "gender",
                          child: Material(
                            child: new Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                InkWell(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      if (isFemaleSelected) {
                                        isFemaleSelected = false;
                                      } else {
                                        isFemaleSelected = true;
                                      }
                                    });
                                  },
                                  child: Opacity(
                                    child: Image.asset(
                                      "assets/woman.png",
                                      height: height / 4,
                                      width: width / 2 - 12,
                                    ),
                                    opacity: isFemaleSelected ? 1.0 : 0.30,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                InkWell(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      if (isFemaleSelected) {
                                        isFemaleSelected = false;
                                      } else {
                                        isFemaleSelected = true;
                                      }
                                    });
                                  },
                                  child: Opacity(
                                    opacity: !isFemaleSelected ? 1.0 : 0.30,
                                    child: Image.asset(
                                      "assets/boy.png",
                                      height: height / 4,
                                      width: width / 2 - 12,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  flex: 1,
                ),
                InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {

                      });
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (BuildContext) =>
                                  new HeightWeightSelection(isFemaleSelected
                                      ? "assets/woman.png"
                                      : "assets/boy.png")));
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 12.0),
                      child: new Image.asset(
                        "assets/next.png",
                        height: 64.0,
                        width: 64.0,
                      ),
                    )),
                new AdmobBannerWrapper(adUnitId: getBannerAdUnitId(),adSize: bannerSize,key: _globalKey,),
               /* new AdmobBanner(
                  adUnitId: getBannerAdUnitId(),
                  adSize: bannerSize,
                  listener:
                      (AdmobAdEvent event, Map<String, dynamic> args) {
                    handleEvent(event, args, 'Banner');
                  },
                ),*/
              ],
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
```

I don't want to call the AdmobBannerWrapper every time I press my image button at the bottom.AdmobBannerWrapper should be loaded once only but the thing is whenever I click the Next Image it load AdmobBannerWrapper method every time.

Comment: if you don't want to rebuild the AdmobBannerWrapper again,then move that widget into the parent widget.

Comment: Thanks Darish but my parent widget is Column wrapped in Scaffold of the Statefull Class.

Comment: it is not clear why you want to keep the AdmobBannerWrapper in the child widget. Could you please explain your use case?

Comment: Wait I will upload my whole class so you can better understand it.

Comment: `(adUnitId: getBannerAdUnitId()` don't do that. You may want to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52249578/how-to-deal-with-unwanted-widget-build

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Build it in `initState()` then use it's reference wherever required it will not build again until parent widget reinitialized.

```
  var banner;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    bannerSize = AdmobBannerSize.BANNER;
    banner = AdmobBannerWrapper(adUnitId: getBannerAdUnitId(),adSize: bannerSize,key:_globalKey,);
  }
```

than call it in by reference here `banner`

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Container(
          width: width,
          child: new Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Flexible(
                        child: new Hero(
                          tag: "gender",
                          child: Material(
                            child: new Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                InkWell(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      if (isFemaleSelected) {
                                        isFemaleSelected = false;
                                      } else {
                                        isFemaleSelected = true;
                                      }
                                    });
                                  },
                                  child: Opacity(
                                    child: Image.asset(
                                      "assets/woman.png",
                                      height: height / 4,
                                      width: width / 2 - 12,
                                    ),
                                    opacity: isFemaleSelected ? 1.0 : 0.30,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                InkWell(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      if (isFemaleSelected) {
                                        isFemaleSelected = false;
                                      } else {
                                        isFemaleSelected = true;
                                      }
                                    });
                                  },
                                  child: Opacity(
                                    opacity: !isFemaleSelected ? 1.0 : 0.30,
                                    child: Image.asset(
                                      "assets/boy.png",
                                      height: height / 4,
                                      width: width / 2 - 12,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  flex: 1,
                ),
                InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {

                      });
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (BuildContext) =>
                                  new HeightWeightSelection(isFemaleSelected
                                      ? "assets/woman.png"
                                      : "assets/boy.png")));
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 12.0),
                      child: new Image.asset(
                        "assets/next.png",
                        height: 64.0,
                        width: 64.0,
                      ),
                    )),
                banner, /*this is our variable */
               /* new AdmobBanner(
                  adUnitId: getBannerAdUnitId(),
                  adSize: bannerSize,
                  listener:
                      (AdmobAdEvent event, Map<String, dynamic> args) {
                    handleEvent(event, args, 'Banner');
                  },
                ),*/
              ],
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Yes did the same for now. Thanks :)

Comment: Any idea about how to use keys to achieve this?

Comment: Keys won't be of help here once parent widget build it by default rebuild children with it.

Comment: You are the real hero !!! Thank you so much. It litterally save my life

Comment: Best approach!... Works very fine. Thank you so much for this answer

Comment: perfect answer.

Answer (score 1):

Put it inside a stateless widget:

```dart
class AdBanner extends StatelessWidget{
  final adUnitId;
  final adSize;

  const AdBanner({Key key, this.adUnitId, this.adSize}) : super(key: key);

  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return AdmobBannerWrapper(
      adUnitId: getBannerAdUnitId(),
      adSize: bannerSize,
      key: _globalKey,
      );
  }
}
```

next time when you call `setState` if the parameters are unchanged, it is not going to get rebuilt.

Comment: Can this stateless widget be called as part of stateful widget build widget tree hierarchy ??