# future builder keeps rebuilding on every setstate

Tags: flutter, dart, future

I am building an app which uses an api and I am using the future builder to fetch the data but the problem is when the state changes it rebuilds and I want to prevent this from happen.

Thanks,

Comment: You may want to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52249578/how-to-deal-with-unwanted-widget-build

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try using this :

```
class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
 _ExampleState createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
 Future<response> future;

 @override
 void initState() {
   future = _asyncmethodCall();
   super.initState();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return FutureBuilder(
  future: future,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    // create some layout here
  },
 );
 }

Future<someResponse> _asyncmethodCall() async {
 // async code here
 }
}
```

similar question: [How to deal with unwanted widget build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52249578/how-to-deal-with-unwanted-widget-build)