# Flutter, Difference between a firestore direct query and a query in FutureBuilder?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

I'm not sure if it is better to query await in initState or if it is better to create a FutureBuilder.

The FutureBuilder is constantly reorganized for each setState, and the animation effect is hidden due to the loading screen (It is a short time, but if the data is not completely ready, I set it to show the loading screen).

So in many situations, I think that using FutureBuilder is not a good idea, so I ask.

Comment: @eyllanesc , Don't exclude Flutter from the title. FutureBuilder and initState are functions that exist only in Flutter. Excluding Flutter in the title is not suitable for the title.

Answer (score 1):

Firestore direct query will return u stream of data which u can use using `StreanBuilder` widget and every update in ur firestore will get reflect there

On other hand query in `FutureBuilder` is just `async` & `await` function which get executed once

Comment: if u r facing rebuilding of future builder on each state change u can view this question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60990519/future-builder-keeps-rebuilding-on-every-setstate/60990674#60990674

Comment: thanks but I think you misunderstood. first of all, I do not want to use StreamBuilder I just want to use simple query only once. and the way you suggested with the link is exactly the way you do initState, as I mentioned above. My question is that Future Builder is being called again through setState in various parts in many ways, so I am trying to confirm whether it is not good to use it.

Comment: if u use it in `init` state then it will gets called once and yes `FutureBuilder` is very good widget to use for network calls