# AsyncMemoizer in Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, future

How do you memoize your futures? I am using a `FutureBuilder` that gets items data by some params.

I found [here](https://medium.com/saugo360/flutter-my-futurebuilder-keeps-firing-6e774830bc2) a suggestion to use `AsyncMemoizer`, however it looks like it's missing from the `dart:async` package.

Are there alternatives?

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52249578/how-to-deal-with-unwanted-widget-build

Comment: `AsyncMemoizer` is part of [`package:async`](https://pub.dev/packages/async), not `dart:async`.

Comment: Ahhh thanks @jamesdlin, that's it!!

Answer (score 20):

```
import 'package:async/async.dart';
```

Answer (score 1):

First add dependency:

```
dart pub add async
```

Then import and use it:

```
import 'package:async/async.dart';
...
final _memoizer = AsyncMemoizer();
```