# how to prevent setState from rebuild in flutter

Tags: flutter, widget, state

is there a way to prevent setState to rebuild? because I have to show my state inside widget `Text` but whenever I click another tab and back again to my main screen... the state always re-build and I am getting null

Comment: no, it is not possible

Comment: is there another method, so that whenever I click another tab... I can still access my last data

Comment: i have no idea what tab you mean

Comment: I have bottom tab navigator in my screen.. so I am doing setState in my first tab screen, and whenever I click my bottom tab... setState always rebuild and I can not get my data

Comment: Sounds like you want to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52249578/how-to-deal-with-unwanted-widget-build

Comment: Are you using a PageView by any chance? Could we see your widget tree to get some context?

Answer (score 0):

you can use AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin to save the state of app.

@override
// TODO: implement wantKeepAlive
bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

using this constuctor.