# Flutter main() runs twice

Tags: flutter

When i was debugging why widgets are building again and again, and found this issue.

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Inside build');
    return MaterialApp( home: Container(child: Text('Hello World')));
 }
}
```

Output: 
flutter: Inside build

flutter: Inside build

Can someone explain why it printed twice? is it really rebuilding the MyApp() twice?

Comment: Idk but I tried this:void main() {
  print('Inside build');
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp( home: Container(child: Text('Hello World')));
  }
} and run only once.

Comment: It might be a double check to constructor or idk but main run only once.

Comment: Can you please let me know what to check ?

Comment: You are printing inside the build method which could run for many reasons. If you are doing hot reload it will run, but the main should be running once, you can add a print statement in main to confirm this.

Comment: You are correct, when i replace in main it printed only once but if it in first widget, it printed multiple times when started fresh. Any idea why it is printed multiple times ?

Comment: Did your screen changed size or changed orientation? Any changes to the screen will trigger a rebuild. Have a read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52249578/how-to-deal-with-unwanted-widget-build

Answer (score 1):

Flutter `main()` doesn't run twice, but since `print()` has been placed inside `Widget build`, a likely scenario is that something has caused for a screen rebuild. Common causes would be `setState()` has been called or a change in screen orientation has been made.