# How do I stop listening to a stream that a parent widget's streambuilder is listening to?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream

Let's say I have a widget called the TheGroupListPage. This widget has a StreamBuilder, which will listen to a `Stream<List<Group>>` and rebuild a ListView() of groups accordingly. Each item in the list is clickable and sends you to a another page called `TheGroupPage(GroupModel group)`.

So now I am on `TheGroupPage(GroupModel group)` and I only care about a single group. But my problem is that the StreamBuilder will continue to listen to a `Stream<List<Group>>`. So how do I stop this?

The only way I can think off is to make TheGroupList page a statefull widget and give it a stream controller. Then somehow close that controller and cancel the subscription once I arrive at TheGroupPage().

But there must be a more elegant way right?

Just to be clear. This is not about unwanted building as talked about here

[How to deal with unwanted widget build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52249578/how-to-deal-with-unwanted-widget-build)

It's about minimizing data usage.