# Flutter: How to receive new Data and update Widget without rebuildung

Tags: flutter, dart, websocket, reload, setstate

I'm currently facing an annoying I think design problem made by myself and flutter :D

In my widgets I work with FutureBuilder. When the Widget gets created, it fetches initial the data - everything's fine.
Now I got a WebSocket connection which sends me updated data. I pass this data to my widget and now I am facing the problem that either I change the data and the Widget does not reload or I additionally use setState and the widget will update itself and again fetches new data because it's rebuild and futurebuilder comes into play again.
That's not efficient at all.
How can I prevent this behavior.

I think about, that my Structure is maybe not right for this flutter behavior and therefore I maybe have to load the data initially outside the widget, pass em in via constructor and set a listener inside my Widget for the WebSocket notification and then call setState... right?

Here an short example that does rebuild and therefore again fetches data by itself -> so not my desired solution:

```
class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {

  Stream wsData;

  _ExampleState() {
    wsData.listen((event) {
      setState(() {
        //update data
      });
    });
  }

  _getData() {
    // Call network manager and fetch data
    return {'fetchedData': 'data'};
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: FutureBuilder(
          future: _getData(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.data != null) {
              Text('data arrived: ' + snapshot.data.toString());
            } else {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52249578/how-to-deal-with-unwanted-widget-build/52249579#52249579

Comment: @RemiRousselet Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution:
In my use case it just wouldn't work with Streambuilder. The data that were passed into the Widget after new data came from the stream were the same somehow..
Now I am using FutureBuilder to fetch the data initial and pass a Stream to my Widget. The Widget listens to changes on the Stream and updates itself..

Also, like mentioned from @Rémi Rousselet, I start the fetch process in the **initState** method and assign it to a local future variable, instead of triggering the fetch directly with FutureBuilder.

Comment: can you provide a minimal code as an example? i'm facing the same issue.. thanks..

Answer (score 4):

If you have a data source which constantly updates itself, you can use a StreamBuilder instead of FutureBuilder. StreamBuilder listens to the data source and rebuilds the widget after every update it gets from it.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It almost works! 
Every time when the stream updates it brings the widget to update itself - but with the same data. 
So my snapshot.data has different data that i pass in, but inside the widget the data remain the same. I watch the data in didUpdateWidget to see if they are the same, and they are.
I tried to create the widget with new in the parent widget, but it's not working..
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Recently I also faced this problem, where I was passing data from another class with **setState**. The data was updated initially using **initState** then I was changing that particular data using a local variable, but when new data arrived from the parent class this was not updating.

later I found `didUpdateWidget` method

```
@override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant ExampleClass oldWidget) {
    print("didUpdateWidget: ${widget.value}");
    selectedIndex = widget.value.toInt().toString(); //local variable
    list.clear(); // list with data
    _buildList(); // list will rebuild with new data
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }
```

basically using this *override* method in the **stateful** class we can do something whenever there is a change in the widget.
Now I can update the data using local and parent variables.