# Flutter: Page rebuilds unlogically

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a page in my flutter app that is only built to display my app's logo and then go to another page. For some reason I can not figure out it runs the build method multiple times even though it is called once.

Here is the code:

```
class LoadingPage extends StatelessWidget {
  int i = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    i++;
    print(i);
    test(context);
    test2();
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.asset("assets/images/logo.png"),
            SizedBox(
              height: Responsive.deviceHeight(context) * 0.05,
            ),
            LoadingRotating.square(
              backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
              borderColor: Colors.white,
              borderSize: 5.0,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void test(BuildContext context) {
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {
      print("H");
      Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ProductListPage()),
        (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
      );
    });
  }

  void test2(){
    print("H2");
  }
}
```

I have expected to print the following:

```
1
H2
H
```

But the result is:

```
I/flutter (20904): 1
I/flutter (20904): H2
I/flutter (20904): 1
I/flutter (20904): H2
I/flutter (20904): H
I/flutter (20904): H
```

Can someone explain this behavior?

Thank you

Comment: and there is an unhandled exception but it appeared before running to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should treat the `build` method as if it will be called multiple times. There is no guarantee that it will only be called once. Check this answer for more detailed information: [How to deal with unwanted widget build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52249578/how-to-deal-with-unwanted-widget-build)