# Flutter Streambuilders rebuilds unnecessarily

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

In my app I have two screens in which I am showing data from firestore using `streambuilders` and also using `Navigator.push()` to move between screens. When streambuilders fetches data it rebuilds its descendants and shows the data.Everything is working fine till here but when I move to second screen the streambuilder  on the first screen rebuilds again.

Correct me if I am wrong here
(If streambuilder is rebuilding again means it creates a new stream and fetches the data again from firestore everytime I move between screens).

If on rebuilding data is not fectched again from firestore then there is no problem but if it does then how to solve this?

code for FirstScreen

```
class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    print('FirstScreen');

    return Scaffold( 
      body: Center(
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SecondScreen())),

          child: Container(
            child: StreamBuilder(
              stream: Firestore.instance.collection('items').snapshots(),
              builder: (context,snap){

                print('FirstScreen : ${snap.connectionState}');

                if(snap.hasData)
                return Text(snap.data.documents[0]['name']);

                else return CircularProgressIndicator();
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

code for second screen

```
class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    print('SecondScreen');
    
    return Scaffold( 
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: StreamBuilder(
            stream: Firestore.instance.collection('products').snapshots(),
            builder: (context,snap){

              print('SecondScreen : ${snap.connectionState}');

              if(snap.hasData)
              return Text(snap.data.documents[0]['name']);

              else return CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

when FirstScreen loads

```
I/flutter ( 6416): FirstScreen build
I/flutter ( 6416): FirstScreen : ConnectionState.waiting
I/flutter ( 6416): FirstScreen : ConnectionState.active
```

when move to SecondScreen

```
I/flutter ( 6416): FirstScreen build
I/flutter ( 6416): FirstScreen : ConnectionState.waiting
I/flutter ( 6416): FirstScreen : ConnectionState.active
I/flutter ( 6416): SecondScreen build
I/flutter ( 6416): SecondScreen : ConnectionState.waiting
I/flutter ( 6416): SecondScreen : ConnectionState.active
I/flutter ( 6416): FirstScreen build
I/flutter ( 6416): FirstScreen : ConnectionState.waiting
I/flutter ( 6416): FirstScreen : ConnectionState.active
```

Comment: U can subscribe to a `stream` ,i.e, u get data when it's available. I doubt that new data can be requested from a `stream` object. In the builder add this code `if (snap.data.documentChanges.length != 0) print('new data available');`. This way you will know when the `widget` was build with new data from firestore.

Comment: But my concern here is why the stream builder is rebuilding when I move to another page and did the stream builder read the data again from firestore or just showing data fetched by it earlier?

Comment: You probably want to read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52249578/how-to-deal-with-unwanted-widget-build