# Null check operator used on a null value error flutter

Tags: flutter, validation, null

i am trying to implement the registration activity in the app and working with the textFields.
My validator is throwing "Null check operator used on a null value" in the line: `String error = widget.validateFunction(val)!;`

if I remove the '!' it gives me error: `A value of type 'String?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'.`
How do I work around it? Thank you!

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64278595/null-check-operator-used-on-a-null-value

Comment: try change String error = 
to String? error =