# How to convert Widget? to Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, dart-null-safety

- The following code will make an error, and the return value is Widget? instead of Widget. I want to be able to force Widget? to Widget, but how to do it?

```
/// Get the parent widget in the subtree
class ContextRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Context test"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Builder(builder: (context) {
          // Find the nearest parent up in the Widget tree `Scaffold` widget
          Scaffold? scaffold = context.findAncestorWidgetOfExactType<Scaffold>();
          // Return the title of AppBar directly, here is actually Text ("Context test")
          Widget? widget1 = (scaffold!.appBar as AppBar).title;
          return widget1;
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Although the shortest way to do it is using the Bang `!` operator

```dart
Widget widget = nullableWidget!;
```

But I'd recommend you to use `?.` to prevent [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64278595/6618622)

```dart
Widget widget = nullableWidget ?? Container(); // Or some other widget.
```

To answer your question:

```dart
return widget ?? Container(); // Safe
return widget!; // Could cause runtime error.
```

Comment: Can you explain the principle of solving the problem in the first case? thanks.  - "return widget ?? Container(); // Safe"

Comment: @pigfly For hypothetical reason, let's say there's was no title in the `AppBar` (title was `null`), this makes your `widget1` `null` and returning `null` from `Widget` is an error. By using `widget ?? Container()`, we make sure that we return at least a `Container` widget to prevent this error. Hope you get the idea.

Comment: Understood. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Null assertion operator / bang operator](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#null-assertion-operator)( **!** )

```
return widget1!;
```