# Error loading AssetManifest.json, e: Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, dart

When I launch my application I get an exception `Error loading AssetManifest.json, e: Null check operator used on a null value` and I have no clue where it is coming from. Contrary to the question [Null check operator used on a null value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64278595/null-check-operator-used-on-a-null-value) I am not using a bang operator anywhere except for this short code piece:

```
return Text(
      widget.text,
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1!.copyWith(
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
      ),
    );
```

The exception is thrown after all calls to this code here so this cannot be the source.

I have no clue what `Error loading AssetManifest.json` means either and could only find solutions for similar sounding issues but none resolved my problem.

I also opened a GitHub issue with results of `flutter run --verbose`, `flutter analyze` and `flutter doctor -v`: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/85457

It would be great if someone could aid me with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following a reply to https://github.com/material-foundation/google-fonts-flutter/issues/172, I fixed it by adding this line in `main()` before calling `runApp`:

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
```