# On flutter run command showing Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: android, flutter, dart, terminal, runtime-error

```
Null check operator used on a null value
package:pub/src/io.dart 1036:47                                dartConfigDir.<fn>
package:pub/src/io.dart 1046:2                                 dartConfigDir
package:pub/src/io.dart                                        dartConfigDir
package:pub/src/system_cache.dart 92:33                        new SystemCache
package:pub/src/command.dart 51:39                             PubCommand.cache
package:pub/src/command.dart 65:70                             PubCommand.entrypoint
package:pub/src/command/get.dart 54:11
```

showing above error on flutter run.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64278595/null-check-operator-used-on-a-null-value

Comment: You pass null value if you check null condition so you add require in passing parameter