# I have a problem with Null Safety an the problem is 'Null check operator used on a null value'

Tags: flutter, bloc, dart-null-safety, cubit, null-safety

It happened when getting some data from firebase and decoding them using model,
and here is the method:

```
UserModel? userModel;
void getUser() {
emit(GetUserLoadingsState());

FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(uId).get().then((value) {
  userModel = UserModel.fromJson(value.data()!);
  emit(GetUserSuccessState());
}).catchError((error) {
  emit(GetUserErrorState(error.toString()));
});
```

}

Calling the method

```
return BlocProvider(
  create: (BuildContext context) => AppCubit()..getUser(),
  child: BlocConsumer<AppCubit, AppStates>(
    listener: (context, state) {},
    builder: (context, state) {
      return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: lightTheme,
        home: startWidget,
      );
    },
  ),
);
```

and consumer

```
BlocConsumer<AppCubit, AppStates>(
  listener: (context, state) {},
  builder: (context, state) {
    var user = AppCubit.get(context).userModel!;
```

Comment: I get data from firebase successfully but when using the user model the error happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order your error message and your code you used null check operator `!` in 2 fields;

1. Field should be like this;

```dart
UserModel? userModel;
void getUser() {
emit(GetUserLoadingsState());

FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(uId).get().then((value) {
  if (value.exists) {
    userModel = UserModel.fromJson(value.data()!);
    emit(GetUserSuccessState());
  }
}).catchError((error) {
  emit(GetUserErrorState(error.toString()));
});
```

2. Field should be like this;

```dart
BlocConsumer<AppCubit, AppStates>(
  listener: (context, state) {},
  builder: (context, state) {
    if (AppCubit.get(context).userModel != null)
      var user = AppCubit.get(context).userModel!;
```

**You shouldn't use the `!` null check operator unless you know that your value is not null.**

Comment: Good reply - and probably exactly the solution I'd recommend.  I'd encourage the OP to explore other alternatives as well, including [Null check operator used on a null value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67990442/421195), and [Flutter Campus: Null check operator used on a null value](https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/225/null-check-operator-used-on-a-null-value/)

Comment: @paulsm4 thank you very much