# Flutter: LateInitializationError" Field"_camera@26505073' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, camera

this flutter code used to work but after an update it does not work anymore and I absolutely have been struggling for hours on it.
The error says

```
LateInitializationError: Field '_camera@26505073' has not been initialized.
```

Here is my Code

```
class _CameraFlowState extends State<CameraFlow> {
  // 2
  late CameraDescription _camera;
  bool _shouldShowCamera = false;

  int len = 0;

  // 3
  List<MaterialPage> get _pages {
    return [
      // Show Gallery Page
      MaterialPage(
          child: GalleryPage(
              shouldLogOut: widget.shouldLogOut,
              shouldShowCamera: () => _toggleCameraOpen(true))),
      // Show Camera Page
      if (_shouldShowCamera)
        MaterialPage(
            child: CameraPage(
                camera: _camera,
                didProvideImagePath: (imagePath) {
                  _toggleCameraOpen(false);
                }))
    ];
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getCamera();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // 4
    return Navigator(
      pages: _pages,
      onPopPage: (route, result) => route.didPop(result),
    );
  }

  // 5
  void _toggleCameraOpen(bool isOpen) {
    setState(() {
      _shouldShowCamera = isOpen;
    });
  }

  Future<void> _getCamera() async {
    final camerasList = await availableCameras();
    setState(() {
      final firstCamera = camerasList.first;
      _camera = firstCamera;
    });
  }
}
```

I tried doing this

```
CameraDescription? _camera;
```

But then I get

```
Null check operator used on a null value.
```

How can I fix this problem? Please help me out...

Comment: The error indicates that you are trying to use the `_camera`  before it got any value. That problem is not solved by making it nullable or late. The problem must be fixed by ensuring your program can either handle the case of the variable being `null`, or make use of `FutureBuilder` to handle the async nature of that variable.

Comment: Visit this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64278595/null-check-operator-used-on-a-null-value