# Null check operator used on a null value. The relevant error-causing widget was StreamBuilder<UserModel?>

Tags: flutter

hi every one hope you doing well I have a code to develop an app by flutter language but this error appears to me in list.dart. this list.dart file should display the posts from firebase with the images if there are.

and I don't know the answer

this is the code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:insight_software/models/postModel.dart';
import 'package:insight_software/other_screen/userFunction.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../models/user.dart';

class ListPost extends StatefulWidget {
  ListPost({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ListPostState createState() => _ListPostState();
}

class _ListPostState extends State<ListPost> {
  UserService _userService = UserService();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<postModel?> posts = Provider.of<List<postModel?>>(context);
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: posts.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final Post = posts[index];
        
        return StreamBuilder(
            stream: _userService.getUserInfo(Post!.creator),
            builder:
                (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<UserModel?> snapshot) {
              // if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              //   return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              // }
              return ListTile(
                title: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 15, 0, 15),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      snapshot.data!.profileImageUrl != ''
                          ? CircleAvatar(
                              radius: 20,
                              backgroundImage:
                                  NetworkImage(snapshot.data!.profileImageUrl))
                          : Icon(
                              Icons.person,
                              size: 30,
                            ),
                      SizedBox(width: 10),
                      Text(snapshot.data!.name),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                subtitle: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 15, 0, 15),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(Post.post),
                          SizedBox(height: 20),
                          Text(Post.timestamp.toDate().toString())
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Divider(),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

who is knowing how I can solve this problem please help me.

my postModel class:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class postModel {
  final String id;
  final String creator;
  final String post;
  final Timestamp timestamp;

  postModel(
      {required this.id,
      required this.creator,
      required this.post,
      required this.timestamp});
}
```

my userModel class:

```
class UserModel {
  final String id;
  final String bannerImageUrl;
  final String profileImageUrl;
  final String name;
  final String email;

  UserModel({
    required this.id,
    required this.bannerImageUrl,
    required this.profileImageUrl,
    required this.name,
    required this.email,
  });
}
```

and this is the getUserInfo

```
UserModel? _userFromFirebaseSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot != null
        ? UserModel(
            id: snapshot.id,
            name: snapshot.get('First Name') ?? '',
            profileImageUrl: snapshot.get('profileImageUrl') ?? '',
            bannerImageUrl: snapshot.get('bannerImageUrl') ?? '',
            email: snapshot.get('email') ?? '',
          )
        : null;
  }

  Stream<UserModel?> getUserInfo(uid) {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("Users")
        .doc(uid)
        .snapshots()
        .map(_userFromFirebaseSnapshot);
  }
```

Comment: Please write your 'postModel' & 'UserModel' Class.

Comment: I added them to the question

Comment: I've  updated my below answer according your Class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs when you use a bang operator (!) on a nullable instance which wasn't initialized.

```
String? foo; // Nullable String

void main() {
  var len = foo!.length; // Runtime error: Null check operator used on a null value
}
```

For more details, you can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67990442/11675817).

So you can update your code:

```
stream: _userService.getUserInfo(Post!.creator),
```

with `stream: _userService.getUserInfo(Post?.creator ?? ''),`

and `snapshot.data!.profileImageUrl != ''`

with `(snapshot.data?.profileImageUrl ?? '') != ''`

and `NetworkImage(snapshot.data!.profileImageUrl))`

with `NetworkImage(snapshot.data?.profileImageUrl) ?? '')`

and `Text(snapshot.data!.name),`

with `Text(snapshot.data?.name ?? ''),`

Comment: thank you so much is working know❤️

Comment: So please accept my answer by clicking tick mark next to the my answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: there is a small error that appears to me the name in this line    Text(snapshot.data?.name ?? ''), should be displayed on the simulator but it its not

Comment: It's because that 'snapshot.data.name' is null so snapshot.data?.name ?? '' returns an empty String.

Comment: how I can fix it ?

Comment: It happens because '_userService.getUserInfo' returns data that contains name = null. You should find that reason.

Comment: Yes, and you should fix that in there.

Comment: I update the question and add the getUserInfo could you take a look and help me please

Comment: Are you sure that 'First Name' in 'name: snapshot.get('First Name') ?? '', ' is correct?! Maybe its spelling is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> **Error:** Null check operator used on a null value

Two way you solve this.

1. in your model class set variable nullable

   `final String? profileImageUrl;` Use **?**.

Or

2. Set default value if null.

   `profileImageUrl ?? ''` if value is null => **?? ''**.