# flutter _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)

Tags: firebase, flutter

I wrote this code, but I got the error.

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized;
  if (kIsWeb) {
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: const FirebaseOptions(
        apiKey: 'xxx',
        appId: 'xxx',
        messagingSenderId: 'xxxx',
        projectId: 'xxxx',
        storageBucket: 'xxx',
      ),
    );
  } else {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
  }
```

`Exception has occurred. _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)`

where has a problem? I think this code is correct.

Comment: See this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64278595/null-check-operator-used-on-a-null-value) to a similar question. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: @nonsocchi I'd saw it and tried it, but still cannot solve.