# Null check operator used on a null value using the GetX package

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

My app launches successfully without warnings, but as soon as I try to save items via the add to cart controller I get the error with warnings as shown below. I'm not sure what to make of this error at this moment.

I understand that the use of (!) bang is referenced but still, I expect that not to be the problem since I have successfully fetched the instances I need to for executing functions in my controllers. I would appreciate any guidance and understanding if this issue has to do with my code or it's a flutter problem on my machine.

**cart_controller with the error showing in line 17**

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:izinto_on_demand/models/popular_specialty_model.dart';
import '../helpers/data/repository/cart_repo.dart';
import '../models/cart_model.dart';
import '../utils/colors.dart';

class CartController extends GetxController {
  final CartRepo cartRepo;
  CartController({required this.cartRepo});
  Map<int, CartModel> _items = {};

  Map<int, CartModel> get items => _items;

  void addItem(SpecialtyModel specialty, int quantity) {
    var totalQuantity = 0;
    if (_items.containsKey(specialty.id!)) {
      _items.update(specialty.id!, (value) {
        // totalQuantity = value.quantity! + quantity;

        return CartModel(
            id: value.id,
            name: value.name,
            price: value.price,
            time: DateTime.now().toString(),
            img: value.img,
            material: value.material,
            quantity: value.quantity! + quantity,
            isExist: true,
            provider: value.provider);
      });

      if (totalQuantity <= 0) {
        _items.remove(specialty.id);
      }
    } else {
      if (quantity > 0) {
        _items.putIfAbsent(specialty.id!, () {
          return CartModel(
              id: specialty.id,
              name: specialty.name,
              price: specialty.price,
              time: DateTime.now().toString(),
              img: specialty.img,
              material: specialty.material,
              quantity: quantity,
              isExist: true,
              provider: specialty.provider);
        });
      } else {
        Get.snackbar('Item count', 'Please select items to add to cart',
            backgroundColor: AppColors.mainColor, colorText: Colors.white);
      }
    }
  }

  bool existInCart(SpecialtyModel, specialty) {
    if (_items.containsKey(specialty.id)) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  int getQuantity(SpecialtyModel specialty) {
    var quantity = 0;
    if (_items.containsKey(specialty.id!)) {
      _items.forEach((key, value) {
        if (key == specialty.id) {
          quantity = value.quantity!;
        }
      });
    }
    return quantity;
  }

  int get totalItems {
    var totalQuantity = 0;
    _items.forEach((key, value) {
      totalQuantity += value.quantity!;
    });
    return totalQuantity;
  }
}
```

**recommended_specialty_controller with the error referenced again in line 81**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:izinto_on_demand/controllers/cart_controller.dart';
import 'package:izinto_on_demand/helpers/data/repository/recommended_specialty_repo.dart';
import 'package:izinto_on_demand/models/popular_specialty_model.dart';
import 'package:izinto_on_demand/utils/colors.dart';

class RecommendedSpecialtyController extends GetxController {
  final RecommendedSpecialtyRepo recommendedSpecialtyRepo;
  RecommendedSpecialtyController({required this.recommendedSpecialtyRepo});
  List<dynamic> _recommendedSpecialtyList = [];
  List<dynamic> get recommendedSpecialtyList => _recommendedSpecialtyList;
  late CartController _cart;

  bool _isLoaded = false;
  bool get isLoaded => _isLoaded;

  int _quantity = 0;
  int get quantity => _quantity;
  int _inCartItems = 0;
  int get inCartItems => _inCartItems + _quantity;

  Future<void> getRecommendedSpecialtyList() async {
    Response response =
        await recommendedSpecialtyRepo.getRecommendedSpecialtyList();
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('got specialties');

      _recommendedSpecialtyList = [];
      _recommendedSpecialtyList
          .addAll(Specialty.fromJson(response.body).specialties);
      print(_recommendedSpecialtyList);
      _isLoaded = true;
      update();
    } else {
      print('this is not working ${response.statusCode}');
    }
  }

  void setQuantity(bool isIncrement) {
    if (isIncrement) {
      _quantity = checkQuantity(_quantity + 1);
    } else {
      _quantity = checkQuantity(_quantity - 1);
      print('decrement ' + _quantity.toString());
    }
    update();
  }

  int checkQuantity(int quantity) {
    if ((_inCartItems + quantity) < 0) {
      Get.snackbar('Item count', 'You don\'t have items',
          backgroundColor: AppColors.mainColor, colorText: Colors.white);
      return 0;
    } else if ((_inCartItems + quantity) > 20) {
      Get.snackbar('Item count', 'Maximum number of items selected',
          backgroundColor: AppColors.mainColor, colorText: Colors.white);
      return 20;
    } else {
      return quantity;
    }
  }

  void initSpecialty(SpecialtyModel specialty, CartController cart) {
    _quantity = 0;
    _inCartItems = 0;
    _cart = cart;
    var exist = false;
    exist = _cart.existInCart(SpecialtyModel, specialty);
    //if exist
    //get from storage _inCartItems=3
    print('exist or not' + exist.toString());
    if (exist) {
      _inCartItems = _cart.getQuantity(specialty);
    }
    print('The quantity in the cart is' + _inCartItems.toString());
  }

  void addItem(SpecialtyModel specialty) {
    if (_quantity > 0) {
      _cart.addItem(specialty, _quantity);
      _quantity = 0;
      _cart.items.forEach((key, value) {
        print('The id is' +
            value.id.toString() +
            ' The quantity is ' +
            value.quantity.toString());
      });
    } else {
      Get.snackbar('Item count', 'You should at least add an item in the cart');
    }

    update();
  }

  int get totalItems {
    return _cart.totalItems;
  }
}
```

**recommended_specialty_detail with the error referenced again in line 212**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:izinto_on_demand/controllers/cart_controller.dart';
import 'package:izinto_on_demand/controllers/popular_specialty_controller.dart';
import 'package:izinto_on_demand/controllers/recommended_specialty_controller.dart';
import 'package:izinto_on_demand/pages/home/main_specialty_page.dart';
import 'package:izinto_on_demand/utils/dimensions.dart';
import 'package:izinto_on_demand/widgets/App_column.dart';
import 'package:izinto_on_demand/widgets/app_icon.dart';
import 'package:izinto_on_demand/widgets/expandable_text.dart';
import '../../models/popular_specialty_model.dart';
import '../../utils/colors.dart';
import '../../widgets/big_text.dart';
import '../../widgets/icon_and_text_widgets.dart';
import '../../widgets/small_text.dart';

class RecommendedSpecialtyDetail extends StatelessWidget {
  int pageId;
  RecommendedSpecialtyDetail({Key? key, required this.pageId})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var specialty = Get.find<RecommendedSpecialtyController>()
        .recommendedSpecialtyList[pageId];
    Get.find<RecommendedSpecialtyController>()
        .initSpecialty(specialty, Get.find<CartController>());
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          //background image
          Positioned(
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            child: Container(
              width: double.maxFinite,
              height: Dimensions.popularSpecialtyImgSize,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  image: AssetImage(specialty.img),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          //icon widgets
          Positioned(
            top: Dimensions.height45,
            left: Dimensions.width20,
            right: Dimensions.width20,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Get.to(() => MainSpecialtyPage());
                    },
                    child: AppIcon(icon: Icons.arrow_back_ios)),
                GetBuilder<RecommendedSpecialtyController>(
                  builder: (controller) {
                    return Stack(
                      children: [
                        AppIcon(icon: Icons.shopping_cart_outlined),
                        Get.find<RecommendedSpecialtyController>().totalItems >=
                                1
                            ? Positioned(
                                right: 0,
                                top: 0,
                                child: AppIcon(
                                  icon: Icons.circle,
                                  size: 20,
                                  iconColor: Colors.transparent,
                                  backgroundColor: AppColors.mainColor,
                                ),
                              )
                            : Container(),
                        Get.find<RecommendedSpecialtyController>().totalItems >=
                                1
                            ? Positioned(
                                right: 3,
                                top: 3,
                                child: BigText(
                                  text:
                                      Get.find<RecommendedSpecialtyController>()
                                          .totalItems
                                          .toString(),
                                  size: 12,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              )
                            : Container()
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          //introduction of specialty services
          Positioned(
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            top: Dimensions.popularSpecialtyImgSize - 20,
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: Dimensions.width20,
                  right: Dimensions.width20,
                  top: Dimensions.height20),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topRight: Radius.circular(Dimensions.radius20),
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(Dimensions.radius20),
                ),
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  AppColumn(
                    text: specialty.name,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: Dimensions.height20,
                  ),
                  BigText(text: 'Introduce'),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: Dimensions.height20,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: ExpandableText(text: specialty.introduction),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: GetBuilder<RecommendedSpecialtyController>(
        builder: (recommendedSpecialty) {
          return Container(
            height: Dimensions.bottomHeightBar,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: Dimensions.height20,
                bottom: Dimensions.height20,
                left: Dimensions.width20,
                right: Dimensions.width20),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: AppColors.buttonBackgroundColor,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(Dimensions.radius20 * 2),
                topRight: Radius.circular(Dimensions.radius20 * 2),
              ),
            ),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: Dimensions.height20,
                      bottom: Dimensions.height20,
                      left: Dimensions.width20,
                      right: Dimensions.width20),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(Dimensions.radius20),
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          recommendedSpecialty.setQuantity(false);
                        },
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.remove_outlined,
                          color: AppColors.signColor,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: Dimensions.width15,
                      ),
                      BigText(
                        text: recommendedSpecialty.inCartItems.toString(),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: Dimensions.width15,
                      ),
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          recommendedSpecialty.setQuantity(true);
                        },
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.add_outlined,
                          color: AppColors.signColor,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: Dimensions.height20,
                      bottom: Dimensions.height20,
                      left: Dimensions.width20,
                      right: Dimensions.width20),
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      recommendedSpecialty.addItem(specialty);
                    },
                    child: BigText(
                      text: 'R${specialty.price}  ' + '|  Add to cart',
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(Dimensions.radius20),
                    color: AppColors.mainColor,
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**What's in the stack trace**

The following _CastError was thrown while handling a gesture:
Null check operator used on a null value

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      CartController.addItem (package:izinto_on_demand/controllers/cart_controller.dart:17:40)
#1      RecommendedSpecialtyController.addItem (package:izinto_on_demand/controllers/recommended_specialty_controller.dart:81:13)
#2      RecommendedSpecialtyDetail.build.. (package:izinto_on_demand/pages/specialty/recommended_specialty_Detail.dart:212:44)
#3      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:198:24)
#4      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:608:11)
#5      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:296:5)

**json map**
{ "Specialties" : [
{
"id": 3,
"price": "150.00",
"createAt": "2022-02-28T13:31:28.497Z",
"img": "assets/image/dry42.jpg",
"quantity" : []
}
]
}

**flutter version*
C:\Users\CLIENT\Desktop\izinto_on_demand>flutter upgrade
Flutter is already up to date on channel stable
Flutter 2.10.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 7e9793dee1 (3 weeks ago) • 2022-03-02 11:23:12 -0600
Engine • revision bd539267b4
Tools • Dart 2.16.1 • DevTools 2.9.2

**dependency injection in main.dart**

```
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Get.find<RecommendedSpecialtyController>().getRecommendedSpecialtyList();
    Get.find<PopularSpecialtyController>().getPopularSpecialtyList();

    Get.lazyPut(() => CartController(cartRepo: Get.find()));
    return GetMaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
```

**specialty model**

```
  late List<SpecialtyModel> _specialties;
  List<SpecialtyModel> get specialties => _specialties;

  Specialty({required specialties}) {
    this._specialties = specialties;
  }

  Specialty.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['Specialties'] != null) {
      _specialties = <SpecialtyModel>[];
      json['Specialties'].forEach((v) {
        _specialties.add(SpecialtyModel.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }
}

class SpecialtyModel {
  int? id;
  String? name;
  String? introduction;
  String? price;
  String? createAt;
  String? img;
  List<double>? location;
  String? provider;
  String? material;

  SpecialtyModel(
      {this.id,
      this.name,
      this.introduction,
      this.price,
      this.createAt,
      this.img,
      this.location,
      this.material,
      this.provider});

  SpecialtyModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    introduction = json['introduction'];
    price = json['price'];
    createAt = json['createAt'];
    img = json['img'];
    material = json['material'];
    location = json['location'].cast<double>();
    provider = json['provider'];
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Null check operator used on a null value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64278595/null-check-operator-used-on-a-null-value)

Comment: pretty sure it's not "a flutter problem on your machine". it simply means that that you use `!` on a null value. By the looks of it `speciality.id`. If you are absolutely sure the response from the server is correct then I assume that parsing the response goes wrong, which would be in the `Specialty.fromJson(response.body)` part. You haven't shared your `Speciality` class so can't tell what goes wrong there

Comment: This is an awesome response because that Speciality class is what's missing but do check it out below and we'll hear if there's an omission on my side or error.

Comment: hmm. looking into that that part looks okay. Except for when `location` is empty then the cast<double> will throw an error. So a safer `location = json['location']?.cast<double>();` could solve that but that doesn't seem to be the error here. Maybe to double check the response you could do a `print(json.toString());` inside `SpecialtyModel.fromJson`?

Comment: When I do that, it fetches the json objects from API as expected, so I guess the Specialty class is not the problem?

Comment: I suppose not, unless you see that one of them has no `id`. Maybe you could do this to have a fallback `id` just in case: `id = json['id'] ?? 0;` and see if it still gives the error

Comment: Okay, Ivo thanks you had in fact detected correctly here, the original Specialties model had `id` as `id = json[id]` instead of `id = json['id']` that's where I made a problem even though in this question it was written correctly in the IDE it was wrongly referenced. Thanks you've been an on-demand hero