# Null check operator used on a null value?

Tags: flutter, dart

**======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following _CastError was thrown building Builder:
Null check operator used on a null value
**

```
productmodel.dart
  final List? size;

main.dart
final Product? product;
List _sizeList=[];

`if(widget.product.size!.isNotEmpty){`
`_sizeList=widget.product.size!;`
`}`
       Container(
                                height: 80,
                                child: ListView.builder(
                                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                itemCount: _sizeList!.length,
                                  itemBuilder: (context,index){
                                    print(_sizeList![index]);
                                    return Text(_sizeList![index]);
                                }),
                              ),
```

Comment: Give a little more context. From your snippet, it looks like size might return null. Try if(widget.product.size != null){ _sizeList=widget.product.size!; }

Comment: i also tried but size code is not worked

Comment: can you show us how you're feeding the **product** into the widget?

Comment: this question already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64278595/null-check-operator-used-on-a-null-value)

Answer (score 1):

You use null-assertion operator (1). For example here:

```
`if(widget.product.size!.isNotEmpty){`
```

It means, that you are sure, that property size isn't null. But in some place in your code variable appears to be null, and you have corresponding error

Comment: I know that problem but i have no solutions