# Flutter : Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

Every time I run my app. It shows

> "Null check operator used on a null value".

I have shown some solutions but couldn't successfully apply them to my code. How do I solve this?

```dart
import 'dart:math';

class bmicalculator {
  bmicalculator({required this.height, required this.weight});

  int height;
  double weight;
  double? bmi;

  String Calculation() {
    bmi = weight / pow(height / 100, 2);
    return bmi!.toStringAsFixed(2);
  }

  String getResult() {
    if (bmi! >= 25) {
      return 'Overweight';
    } else if (bmi! > 18.5) {
      return 'Normal';
    } else
      return 'UnderWeight';
  }

  String getInterpretation() {
    if (bmi! >= 25) {
      return 'String 1';
    } else if (bmi! > 18.5) {
      return 'String 2';
    } else
      return 'String 3';
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Null check operator used on a null value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64278595/null-check-operator-used-on-a-null-value)

Comment: I will encourage you to check null 1st then use `!`.

Answer (score 1):

The null check operator(`!`) is used at `getResult()` and `getInterpretation()` functions. This operator should NOT be used if the value can be null. The `bmi` value can be null, so you don't use the `!` operator if that can be null.

#### Solution

Add condition before using the `bmi` value like below.

```dart
String getResult() {
  if (bmi == null)
    throw Exception(); // or return 'The bmi is null!';

  if (bmi! >= 25) {
    return 'Overweight';
  } else if (bmi! > 18.5) {
    return 'Normal';
  } else
    return 'UnderWeight';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

this would happen when you call `getResult` or `getInterpretation` without calling Calculation previously, and the problem is that you are not initilizing the value of `bmi` which is a String? type and it's initial value is `null`, so when you try to use one of the methods `getResult` or `getInterpretation` you would get error because `bmi` is `null`,

you can solve the issue by initializing the bmi value in the constructor like:

```
  bmicalculator({required this.height, required this.weight}){
        bmi = weight / pow(height / 100, 2);
  }
```