# Null check used on null value

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, dart-null-safety

I keep on getting 'Null check operator used on null value' when i try to write user information onto firestore . How can i possibly fix this error?

here's a snippet of the code where im trying to implement this-

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final UserProvider userProvider = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 1.0,
        iconTheme: const IconThemeData(
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        title: const Text(
          "Inventory",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 60.0, horizontal: 16.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => _selectImage(context),
                child: Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(),
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  height: 210.0,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: _file == null
                          ? const NetworkImage(
                                  'https://i.stack.imgur.com/l60Hf.png')
                              as ImageProvider
                          : MemoryImage(_file!),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                child: TextFieldInput(
                  maxLines: 1,
                  maxLength: TextField.noMaxLength,
                  controller: _mealNameController,
                  labelText: 'Meal Name',
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                child: TextFieldInput(
                  maxLines: 1,
                  maxLength: TextField.noMaxLength,
                  controller: _priceController,
                  labelText: 'price',
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                child: TextFieldInput(
                  maxLines: 5,
                  controller: _mealDescriptionController,
                  labelText: 'Meal description',
                  maxLength: 150,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 28.0),
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  mealSize(context),
                  const SizedBox(height: 9.0),
                  mealSize(context),
                  const SizedBox(height: 9.0),
                  mealSize(context),
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 40.0),
              GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () => addMenu(userProvider.getUser.name),
                  child: const Button(btnText: "Add Food Item")),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

userprovider.dart:

```
    class UserProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  User? _user;

  final AuthController _authMethods = AuthController();

  User get getUser => _user!;

  Future<void> refreshUser() async {
    User user = await _authMethods.getUserDetails();
    _user = user;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

This is the error i get when I call the function:

```
══════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════
The following _CastError was thrown while handling a gesture:
Null check operator used on a null value

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      `UserProvider.getUse`r
package:webite/provider/user_provider.dart:11
#1      _AddMealState.build.<anonymous closure>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking into the answer of this post? Looks oddly similar to me.
[Null check operator used on a null value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64278595/null-check-operator-used-on-a-null-value)

especially on two locations:

```
  User get getUser => _user!; <---- right here
```

````
                        image: _file == null
                          ? const NetworkImage(
                                  'https://i.stack.imgur.com/l60Hf.png')
                              as ImageProvider
                          : MemoryImage(_file!), <--- and here
    ```
````

Comment: so i should more or less if check _user == null?

Comment: sounds like a good idea, you technically shouldn't let a user to write information to the firestore when it's null eitherway

Comment: in this context im only mainly just trying to capture input data from user

Comment: Then the focus should be placed on why the user is currently null when it shouldnt be