# error flutter _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value) using sqlite database

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart, dart-null-safety

i have trouble with my flutter database , i'm using sqlite for database and when i want to run it i have error said that _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value). i already use (!)in my code but still the same ,can anybody help me

my code in dbhelbper

```
Future<List<DistribusiModel>> getAll() async {
    final data = await _database!.query(namaTabel);
    List<DistribusiModel> result =
        data.map((e) => DistribusiModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
    return result;
  }
```

my code from main.dart

```
 FutureBuilder<List<DistribusiModel>>(
              future: databasedistribusi!.getAll(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                print('Hasil: ' + snapshot.data!.toString());
                return ListTile(
                    title: Text('Algoritma dan Pemrograman I'),
                    trailing: Wrap(
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          '3',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 20,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'A',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 20,
                        ),
                        Text('LULUS'),
                      ],
                    )
```

please help me , i need to finish it immediately

sorry for my bad english

i hope anyone can help me whit this problem

Comment: This link may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64278595/null-check-operator-used-on-a-null-value

Comment: i already see that solution but still the same

Answer (score 0):

Firstly make sure the `databasedistribusi` is not null. Beware of using `!` directly without checking null.

and return empty list on null case

```dart
Future<List<DistribusiModel>> getAll() async {
    if(_database==null) return [];
    final data = await _database.query(namaTabel);
    List<DistribusiModel> result =
        data.map((e) => DistribusiModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
    return result;
  }
```

And for the FutureBuilder

```dart
 FutureBuilder<List<DistribusiModel>>(
              future: databasedistribusi?.getAll(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if(snapshot.hasError) return Text("got Error");

                else if(snapshot.hasData){
                   if(snapshot.data.isEmpty) return Text("EmptyData");
                   else return ListView(....);
                }

                return CircularProgressIndicator(); //default
            }
```

More about using [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) and [understanding-null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)