# Flutter Giving null check operator error on the first run in vscode

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to start a new flutter project in vscode, but when I try to run the code which I haven't tampered, it is giving me a `Crash when compiling null, at character offset null: Null check operator used on a null value`

followed by a

```
#0      InferableTypeBuilderMixin.type (package:front_end/src/fasta/builder/type_builder.dart:392:29)
#1      InferableTypeBuilder.inferType (package:front_end/src/fasta/builder/omitted_type_builder.dart:155:12)
#2      SourceLoader.performTopLevelInference (package:front_end/src/fasta/source/source_loader.dart:2358:19)
#3      KernelTarget.buildOutlines.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/kernel/kernel_target.dart:532:14)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      withCrashReporting (package:front_end/src/fasta/crash.dart:122:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      _buildInternal (package:front_end/src/kernel_generator_impl.dart:139:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      withCrashReporting (package:front_end/src/fasta/crash.dart:122:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      generateKernel.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/kernel_generator_impl.dart:47:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      generateKernel (package:front_end/src/kernel_generator_impl.dart:46:10)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      kernelForModule (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/kernel_generator.dart:100:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     SingleShotCompilerWrapper.compileInternal (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/sdk/pkg/vm/bin/kernel_service.dart:412:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     Compiler.compile.<anonymous closure> (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/sdk/pkg/vm/bin/kernel_service.dart:221:45)
<asynchronous suspension>
#12     _processLoadRequest (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/sdk/pkg/vm/bin/kernel_service.dart:914:37)
<asynchronous suspension>


#0      InferableTypeBuilderMixin.type (package:front_end/src/fasta/builder/type_builder.dart:392:29)
#1      InferableTypeBuilder.inferType (package:front_end/src/fasta/builder/omitted_type_builder.dart:155:12)
#2      SourceLoader.performTopLevelInference (package:front_end/src/fasta/source/source_loader.dart:2358:19)
#3      KernelTarget.buildOutlines.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/kernel/kernel_target.dart:532:14)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      withCrashReporting (package:front_end/src/fasta/crash.dart:122:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      _buildInternal (package:front_end/src/kernel_generator_impl.dart:139:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      withCrashReporting (package:front_end/src/fasta/crash.dart:122:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      generateKernel.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/kernel_generator_impl.dart:47:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      generateKernel (package:front_end/src/kernel_generator_impl.dart:46:10)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      kernelForModule (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/kernel_generator.dart:100:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     SingleShotCompilerWrapper.compileInternal (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/sdk/pkg/vm/bin/kernel_service.dart:412:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     Compiler.compile.<anonymous closure> (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/sdk/pkg/vm/bin/kernel_service.dart:221:45)
<asynchronous suspension>
#12     _processLoadRequest (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/sdk/pkg/vm/bin/kernel_service.dart:914:37)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

I don't know what to do, I can't even start a project, someone help!

Comment: I think this can help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64278595/null-check-operator-used-on-a-null-value

Comment: Produced the code which is causing this error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Null check operator used on a null value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64278595/null-check-operator-used-on-a-null-value)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was i was running `$dart run .\lib\main.dart` instead of `$flutter run`