# Flutter - Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to initialize fields from a FirebaseFirestore document using GetXcontroller but I am getting the following error:

> Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value.

The Controller gets created but it doesn't get initialized because of
the null check operator used on null value. Here's my code:

```
class DataController extends GetxController{
  DocumentSnapshot? userDocument;
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  getUserProfileData() {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(auth.currentUser!.uid) //Null check operator used on a null value
        .snapshots()
        .listen((event) {
      userDocument = event;
    });
  }

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    getUserProfileData();
  }
}
```

My error log:

```
E/flutter (11591): #1      DataController.onInit
data_controller.dart:76
E/flutter (11591): #2      GetLifeCycleBase._onStart
lifecycle.dart:66
E/flutter (11591): #3      InternalFinalCallback.call
lifecycle.dart:12
E/flutter (11591): #4      GetInstance._startController
get_instance.dart:253
E/flutter (11591): #5      GetInstance._initDependencies
get_instance.dart:204
E/flutter (11591): #6      GetInstance.find
get_instance.dart:301
E/flutter (11591): #7      GetInstance.put
get_instance.dart:86
E/flutter (11591): #8      Inst.put
extension_instance.dart:89
E/flutter (11591): #9      main
main.dart:23
E/flutter (11591): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11591):
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Null check operator used on a null value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64278595/null-check-operator-used-on-a-null-value)

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you that in this expression

```
auth.currentUser!.uid
```

the value of `currentUser` is null. This means that the user is not authenticated at that point. Make sure to perform user login before reaching this point of your code. As a safeguard you should also manually check if the user is authenticated before calling this chain. For example via

```
if (auth.currentUser != null) {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(auth.currentUser!.uid) //Force unwrapping is now fine here
        // ...
}
```