# Flutter: Null check operator used on a null value on REST API Call values

Tags: flutter

I am facing `Null check operator used on a null value` error when loading the profile page.

In profile page I call the profile details API first and from that I am showing the details like name, email, username and phone number on the UI. When loading the API I will get this error and after API load this error will vanished. I added a null check but that doesn't solve my problem.

**My Code:**

```
class _UserDetailsState extends State<UserDetails> {
  ProfileResponse? profileResponse;
  //created variables
  String phoneNumber = "";
  String fullName = "";
  String email = "";
  String username = "";

  Future<void> fetchData() async {
    try {
      final response = await getProfileDetails();
      if (response?.statusCode == 200) {
        Map<String, dynamic> parsedData = jsonDecode(response!.body);
        setState(() {
          profileResponse = ProfileResponse.fromJson(parsedData);
          //null check added here
          if (profileResponse?.phoneList.length != 0) {
            phoneNumber = profileResponse!.phoneList[0].phoneNumber;
          }
          else {
            phoneNumber = "";
          }
          if(profileResponse?.userTO?.firstName != null){
              fullName = profileResponse!.userTO!.firstName;
            }
          else{
            fullName = "";
          }

          if(profileResponse?.userTO?.lastName != null){
            fullName = fullName + " "+ profileResponse!.userTO!.lastName;
          }

          if(profileResponse?.userTO?.username != null){
            username = profileResponse!.userTO!.username;
          }
          else{
            username = "";
          }

          if(profileResponse?.userTO?.email != null){
            email = profileResponse!.userTO!.email;
          }
          else{
            email = "";
          }
        });
      } else {
      //message
      }
    } catch (error) {
      //message
    }
  }
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    fetchData();
  }
  
  Future<http.Response?> getProfileDetails() async {
      final String url = "API CALL";
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
      return response;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            child: TextField(
              controller: new TextEditingController.fromValue(
                  new TextEditingValue(
                      text: fullName, //value setting
                      selection:
                      new TextSelection.collapsed(
                          offset: profileResponse!.userTO!.firstName.length))),
          ),
          Container(
            child: TextField(
              controller: new TextEditingController.fromValue(
                  new TextEditingValue(
                      text: username, //value setting
                      selection:
                      new TextSelection.collapsed(
                          offset: profileResponse!.userTO!.username.length))),
          ),
          Container(
            child: TextField(
              controller: new TextEditingController.fromValue(
                  new TextEditingValue(
                      text: email, //value setting
                      selection:
                      new TextSelection.collapsed(
                          offset: profileResponse!.userTO!.email.length))),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16),
            child: TextField(
              controller: new TextEditingController.fromValue(
                  new TextEditingValue(
                      text: phoneNumber, //value setting
                      selection:
                      new TextSelection.collapsed(offset: phoneNumber.length))),
        ],
      ),
    );
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Null check operator used on a null value" error occurs when you're trying to access a property or method using the null check operator (!) on a nullable object that is currently null. In your code, the error is likely occurring because you are directly accessing properties of profileResponse!.userTO! and profileResponse!.phoneList[0] without first ensuring that profileResponse is not null. I think the error can go away by changing the built part of your code as follows.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          child: TextField(
            controller: new TextEditingController.fromValue(
              new TextEditingValue(
                text: fullName,
                selection: new TextSelection.collapsed(
                  offset: profileResponse?.userTO?.firstName.length ?? 0, // Null-aware access
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          child: TextField(
            controller: new TextEditingController.fromValue(
              new TextEditingValue(
                text: username,
                selection: new TextSelection.collapsed(
                  offset: profileResponse?.userTO?.username.length ?? 0, // Null-aware access
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          child: TextField(
            controller: new TextEditingController.fromValue(
              new TextEditingValue(
                text: email,
                selection: new TextSelection.collapsed(
                  offset: profileResponse?.userTO?.email.length ?? 0, // Null-aware access
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16),
          child: TextField(
            controller: new TextEditingController.fromValue(
              new TextEditingValue(
                text: phoneNumber,
                selection: new TextSelection.collapsed(
                  offset: profileResponse?.phoneList.isNotEmpty
                      ? profileResponse!.phoneList[0].phoneNumber.length
                      : 0, // Null-aware access
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Is this ChatGPT-generated?

Comment: The answer to the same topic that has been opened before is in the link. For error in Build section ? and ?? used. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64278595/null-check-operator-used-on-a-null-value