# null check operator is used on a null value appear when the current user logout

Tags: android, flutter, dart

If I run the app and the last user account stays logged and click on logs out, this `null check operator is used on a null value`  is what appears in the emulator, and I don't know where the exact error to solve it.

this is my main.dart code

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:water_reminder_app/screens/home_page.dart';
import 'package:water_reminder_app/screens/start_page.dart';
import 'package:water_reminder_app/services/notify_service.dart';
import 'package:water_reminder_app/widgets/database.dart';
import 'package:water_reminder_app/widgets/user_data.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'model/pages_names.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  unawaited(MobileAds.instance.initialize());

  await NotificationServices().init();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);

  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (context) => CloudDataProvider(), child: const MyApp()),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String? profileImagePath;
  User? user;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final cloudDataProvider =
        Provider.of<CloudDataProvider>(context, listen: false);
    final weight = cloudDataProvider.weight;
    final unit = cloudDataProvider.unit;
    final bedtime = cloudDataProvider.bedtime;
    final wakeUpTime = cloudDataProvider.wakeUptime;

    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => UserDataProvider(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => CloudDataProvider(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: user == null
            ? const StartPage()
            : HomePage(
                weight: weight ?? 0,
                unit: unit ?? '',
                bedTime: bedtime ?? '',
                wakeUpTime: wakeUpTime ?? ''),
        onGenerateRoute: MyRoutes.genrateRoute,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the `CloudDataProvider` file

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class CloudDataProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  double? weight;
  String? unit;
  String? bedtime;
  String? wakeUptime;

  void fetchUserData() async {
    final User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

    if (user != null) {
      final userDoc =
          FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(user.uid);

      final userSnapshot = await userDoc.get();

      weight = userSnapshot['weight'] as double;
      unit = userSnapshot['unit'] as String;
      bedtime = userSnapshot['bedtime'] as String;
      wakeUptime = userSnapshot['wake-up time'] as String;
    }

    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

You can find the whole app in this link [gitHub link](https://github.com/ftoome545/Water-Reminder-app)

I tried to use `??` instead of `!` that I found it in this link [Null check operator used on a null value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64278595/null-check-operator-used-on-a-null-value) but the error still there. anyone can know how to fix this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your project and encountered other issues, but I fixed them, and now it's working successfully. I made the following changes:

In the HOME screen, I updated the initialization code:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    User? currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    if (currentUser != null) {
      userAuthID = currentUser.uid;

      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        final userDataProvider =
            Provider.of<UserDataProvider>(context, listen: false);
        userDataProvider.initializeItems(widget.unit);
        getData();
        _loadAd();
      });
    } else {
      // Handle the case when there is no user logged in
      // For example, redirect to login screen
    }
  }
```

The getData method:

```
  void getData() async {
    final userDataProvider =
        Provider.of<UserDataProvider>(context, listen: false);
    sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final itemList = sharedPreferences.getStringList('$userAuthID + items');
    if (itemList != null) {
      final drinkRecords = itemList
          .map((item) => DrinkRecordModel.fromMap(jsonDecode(item)))
          .toList();
      userDataProvider.items =
          ValueNotifier<List<DrinkRecordModel>>(drinkRecords);
    }

    double? amount = sharedPreferences.getDouble('$userAuthID + amount');
    if (amount != null) {
      setState(() {
        userDataProvider.amount = amount;
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: It didn't work, and the error still exists.

Comment: what kind of error?? Because it's running smoothly on my end

Comment: This is what appears in the emulator `I/flutter ( 6291): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 4137 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true.` I think this is because, in the home screen, I added `Navigator.pushNamed(context, startPage);` at the initialization code.

Comment: it is still running fine on my end and I uploaded an updated code zip file here [https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1TdEYqTdOvWBprxqzVCX4HoXzNATJc3OZ?usp=sharing]
if you still face any issue let me know. @Fatima

Comment: It worked with me after I changed `Navigator.pushNamed(context, startPage);` to `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const StartPage()));
      });` at the `else` section in the initState. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

The error should tell you on what line exactly the error happens. I've tried your project and it's actually on login, not logout that a null error happens for me. and the error says

```
E/flutter ( 4930): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
E/flutter ( 4930): #0      _HomeState.getData.<anonymous closure> (package:water_reminder_app/screens/home.dart:103:62)
E/flutter ( 4930): #1      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1203:30)
E/flutter ( 4930): #2      _HomeState.getData (package:water_reminder_app/screens/home.dart:93:5)
```

The second line says `home.dart:103:62` meaning it's in that file on line 103, which is

```
      userDataProvider.amount =
          sharedPreferences.getDouble('$userAuthID + amount')!;
```

Here you use `!` on something that returns null, so maybe change it to

```
      userDataProvider.amount =
          sharedPreferences.getDouble('$userAuthID + amount') ?? 0.0;
```

Maybe it's not the same error that you have, but you should be able to find the exact spot where the error happens in the same way.

Comment: I tried your change, but it didn't work, and I can't find the exact spot where the error happens, because my debug console does not show the line where the error happens. **https://drive.google.com/file/d/17nYp6UK8iX0kfrjt_nRgici2fyyiso5_/view?usp=drive_link**

Answer (score -1):

just add some simple null check & u r good to go,

```
void fetchUserData() async {
    final User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    if (user != null) {
      final userDoc =
          FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(user.uid);
      final userSnapshot = await userDoc.get();
      weight = userSnapshot['weight'] !=null ? userSnapshot['weight'] as double : null;
      unit = userSnapshot['unit'] !=null ? userSnapshot['unit'].toString() : null;
      bedtime = userSnapshot['bedtime'] != null ? userSnapshot['bedtime'].toString() : null;
      wakeUptime = userSnapshot['wake-up time'] !=null ? userSnapshot['wake-up time'].toString() : null;
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
```