# How to setState() and not rebuild tabs in a TabBarView

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, setstate

I have this problem, i have a home page where it has tabs. I like when i switch tabs to make the `TabBar` show black the tab that is selected and also i want to change the color of the whole `Scaffold`. So i made also a custom controller and used it like this:

```
TabController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = TabController(vsync: this, length: 5);
    _controller.index = 1;
    _controller.addListener(() {
      if (!_controller.indexIsChanging) {
         setState(() {
          scaffoldColor = colors[_controller.index];
         });
      }
    });
  }
```

The thing is that in this way all of my tabs are going to be rebuild and this is very bad because i have heavy tasks in few of them.
I also have used `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` in all of the tabs but it didn't fix the problem. By the way i used it like this:

```
class Tab1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Tab1State createState() => _Tab1State();
}

class _Tab1State extends State<Tab1> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    print("Tab 1 Has been built");
    return Text("TAB 1");
  }

  @override
  // TODO: implement wantKeepAlive
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If for heavy tasks you mean a Future, you should place it inside `initState`.

See this answer: [How to load async Stream only one time in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64695992/how-to-load-async-stream-only-one-time-in-flutter).

Comment: no it isn't like that. But it is crucial not to rebuild all of the tabs of the TabBarView

Comment: If your tabs are different bodies of the same Scaffold, I don't know how you can change the color of the Scaffold without rebuilding it. To keep the state of the tabs I used IndexedStack.

Comment: my tabs are different widgets. But yeah are in the same scaffold cause in the AppBar i have the TabBar.
So yeah...