# Flutter build called multiple times

Tags: flutter, state, bloc

I have a bottom nav bar that has a list page that uses a bloc for the state.

```
class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  int _index = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<Widget> _widgets = [
      const ListPage(),
      Scaffold(),
      Scaffold(),
      
    ];

    return Scaffold(
        body: IndexedStack(
          index: _index,
          children: _widgets,
        ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    ...


class ListPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const ListPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (_) =>
          getIt<ListBloc>()..add(const ListEvent.load(limit: 10)),
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(),
          body: const List(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is `build` is beeing called 4 times. This causes the event fetching the list 4 times.

Don't know where to add the event to prevent re-builds.

If I add the event in statefull widget's `initState`. Bloc does not recognize ListBloc beeing  in the context when fetching the bloc down the widget tree.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you have two Scaffolds nested in a parent Scaffold?

Comment: They are placeholders. Still working on that part.

Comment: You should check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52249578/how-to-deal-with-unwanted-widget-build

Answer (score 5):

The best way is to add event in initState of you main route (Route that contains Bottom Navigation). As shown in below code.

```
class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  int _index = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getIt<ListBloc>().add(const ListEvent.load(limit: 10));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<Widget> _widgets = [
      const ListPage(),
      Scaffold(),
      Scaffold(),
      
    ];

    return Scaffold(
        body: IndexedStack(
          index: _index,
          children: _widgets,
        ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    ...


class ListPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const ListPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (_) =>
          getIt<ListBloc>(),
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(),
          body: const List(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: With this. `initState` is called twice.

Comment: No it will not.

Comment: If it solved your issue, please accept my answer then.

Answer (score 3):

you can use StatefulWidget class with KeepAlive, according to official doc (Mark a child as needing to stay alive even when it's in a lazy list that would otherwise remove it).

In code :

```
class YourStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {

//add with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin to the state class

class _YourStatefulWidgetState extends State<YourStatefulWidget > with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {

  //add  super.build(context) under the build method
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  super.build(context);

  return //your widget

   @override
   bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
  }
 }
}
```

Or you can fixed logically by using a Boolean value form your state management class as the value wouldn't change if the widget get rebuild.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is in `MainPage`. When you change selected page in bottom navigation bar you forces the call of `build` of `MainPage` but it recreates `_widgets` variable every time and this forces update child widgets. Move `final _widgets = ...` in class scope, i.e. your variable will be created once.

Also you should `provide` Bloc on level above your bottom navigation bar item i.e. wrap `ListPage` with `BlocProvider`. And than it will be found in tree. Or try to use `Builder` between `BlocProvider` and `SafeArea` in `ListPage`.

To get `ListBloc` you need to use `BlocProvider.of<ListBloc>(context)` in a widget where you need bloc.

Answer (score 2):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
       
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page',con: context,), // passing context
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title, this.con}) : super(key: key); // receiving context
  final String title;
  
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
 
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
 
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
 
        child: Column(
 
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(widget.con).textTheme.headline4, // using received context
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }

 
}
```

Pass the context from one class to another instead of creating a new context every time.. The above example is a default flutter app created when you create a new flutter project. see the comments `passing context`, `receiving context` and `using received context` I think this should resolve the issue..

Comment: Can you explain why passing the context down prevents rebuild in the child. Or for that matter rebuild in the parent as I placed the `create` function in the parent and it didn't work.

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/rendering/best-practices .. ```Generally speaking, there are 2 uses cases for context :``` ```1. Interact with your parents (get/post data mostly)```
```2. Once rendered on screen, get your screen size and position.``` ```The second point is kinda rare. On the other hand, the first point is used nearly everywhere.```