# Offstage Navigators rebuild

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, provider

I have implemented the multiple `Offstage` `Navigators` for the `bottomNavigationBar`, further details can be seen [here](https://medium.com/coding-with-flutter/flutter-case-study-multiple-navigators-with-bottomnavigationbar-90eb6caa6dbf). The problem is that when using this method, each time we select a bottom navigation item, the `FutureBuilder` runs the future method and rebuilds the entire widget, each `Offstage` widget and all their children are also rebuilt.

For each `Offstage` widget, I'm loading data via html request and that means each time I switch a tab, 5 requests will be made.

This is my main `Scaffold` which holds the `bottomNavigationBar`.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TabProvider tabProvider = Provider.of<TabProvider>(context);
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: initProvider(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return WillPopScope(
            onWillPop: _onWillPop,
            child: Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text(tabName[tabProvider.currentTab],
              ),
              body: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                _buildOffstageNavigator(TabItem.feed, tabProvider.currentTab),
                _buildOffstageNavigator(TabItem.explore, tabProvider.currentTab),
                _buildOffstageNavigator(TabItem.guide, tabProvider.currentTab),
                _buildOffstageNavigator(TabItem.map, tabProvider.currentTab),
                _buildOffstageNavigator(TabItem.profile, tabProvider.currentTab),
              ]),
              bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigation(
                currentTab: tabProvider.currentTab,
                onSelectTab: tabProvider.selectTab,
              ),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return Text('Loading');
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

The `FutureBuilder` will initialize the values in my provider so each tab can access the cached data.

The `_buildOffstageNavigator` will return the below

```
return Offstage(
      offstage: currentTab != tabItem,
      child: TabNavigator(
        navigatorKey: navigatorKeys[tabItem],
        tabItem: tabItem,
      ),
    );
```

Below is the Widget which is built inside the `Scaffold` body and hence inside the `Offstage` `Navigator` from above.

```
@override   
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TabProvider tabProvider = Provider.of<TabProvider>(context);
    States stateData = tabProvider.exploreStateCache;
    return Container(
      child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(stateData.stateName),
          Text(stateData.stateDescription),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

I have followed this [articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52249578/how-to-deal-with-unwanted-widget-build) advice for using futures with the provider but something else is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating futures in a build method, which as you have noticed, may be called several times, create them in a place that is invoked only once. For example, a StatefulWidget's initState:

```
class Foo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FooState createState() => _FooState();
}

class _FooState extends State<Foo> {
  Future<MyData> _dataFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _dataFuture = getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => FutureBuilder<MyData>(
        future: _dataFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) => ...,
      );
}
```

A second thing you can improve is reduce the scope of what gets rebuild when the provider provides a new value for `TabProvider`. The context that you call `Provider.of<Data>(context)` gets rebuild when there's a new value for `Data`. That is done most conveniently with the various other widgets offered by the provider package, like `Consumer` and `Selector`.

So remove the `Provider<TabProvder>.of(context)` calls and use `Consumer`s and `Selector`s. For example, to only rebuild the title when a tab is switched:

```dart
AppBar(
  title: Selector<TabProvider, String>(
    selector: (context, tabProvider) => tabName[tabProvider.currentTab],
    builder: (context, title) => Text(title),
  ),
)
```

Selector only rebuilds the `Text(title)` widget, when the result of its `selector` callback is different from the previous value. Similarly for `_buildOffstageNavigator`:

```dart
Widget _buildOffstageNavigator(BuildContext context, TabItem tabItem) {
  return Selector<TabProvider, bool>(
    selector: (context, tabProvider) => tabProvider.currentTab != tabItem,
    builder: (context, isCurrent) => Offstage(
      offstage: isCurrent,
      child: Selector<TabProvider, Key>(
        selector: (context, tabProvider) => tabProvider.navigatorKeys[tabItem],
        builder: (context, tabKey) => TabNavigator(
          navigatorKey: tabKey,
          tabItem: tabItem,
        ),
      ),
    );
}
```

(Beware: All code is untested and contains typos)

Comment: As the `_dataFuture = getData();`  will initialize the variables used by the provider, the init state function cannot use the Provider.of(context). Is there another way around this?

Comment: If you need to use context in initState, you can move the code to didChangeDependencies and make it lazily initialize the variable. For example: `variableInState ??= Provider.of<Data>(context, listen: false);` (only once) or `variableInState = Provider.of<Data>(context);` (widget gets rebuild when Data changes). I’m not sure this helps, as I don’t understand what you mean exactly.