# How to execute db query before return the ui on getx

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I want to get data from db first and then to show it on the ui, how to let this action execute every time before return the ui?

```
class TestScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  // execute this method every time before return the ui.
  data = getDataFromDB();
  
  return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: data.count;
    itemBuilder: ...
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `StatefullWidget` and a `FutureBuilder` to achieve what you want:

```dart
class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExampleState createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  Future<int> future;

  @override
  void initState() {
    future = Future.value(42);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: future,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        // create some layout here
      },
    );
  }
}
```

You can then use `snapshot.hasData` to know whether your future as yet completed or not. If it has, return your list. If it has not, return a loading widget or whatever you want ;)

*Snippet taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/52249579/5990125 which is a similar answer to a different question. Credit to Rémi Rousselet.*

Answer (score 0):

It's better to pass db data before navigate to the specific screen,

```
data = db.query();
Get.ToNamed('TestScreen', arguments: data);

class TestScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: Get.arguments;
    itemBuilder: ...
  );
}
```